# Nodejs exports and module.exports: Why do we need exports anyway?

Tags: node.js

As I read through the some of the answers on [another question on this topic:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js)

I (guess) understand what exports and module.exports are and how they can be used!

What I don't understand is why do we need **exports** anyway since we can perfectly work things out with using only **module.exports**. Besides, If I conceive it good: **exports** has potential to create bugs.

For example:

```
// feature.js
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.greet = function() {
        console.log('Hi, my name is ' + this.name);
    }
}
module.exports = Person;

// app.js
var Person = require(./feature);

var Aron = new Person('Aron');
Aron.greet(); // Hi, my name is Aron
```

You can simply break this working version with using **exports**:

```
exports = Person; // wont' work   
exports.Person = Person; // still won't work (until you resolve it as new Person.Person('Aron') or ..require(..).Person) Which is not readable..
```

Why do we have exports anyway? Can someone explain to me the benefits of using exports instead of module.exports?

Thanks advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are just adding properties to `module.exports` or to `exports`, then you can modify either one and get the same result.  This is because both `module.exports` and `exports` initially point to the exact same object.  So, if you modify one, the other is pointing at the same object so the change will be seen in either one.  `exports` is apparently just provided as a typing shortcut so you don't have to refer to `module.exports`.

So, this is perfectly safe:

```
exports.foo = 123;
```

Or

```
module.exports.foo = 123;
```

Both create exactly the same result and are both safe as they each just assign a property to the same object.

But, if you are creating and assigning a whole new exports object, then you MUST assign that object to `module.exports`.  Assigning it only to `exports` will not do you any good.

The syntax:

```
exports = module.exports = {foo: 1};
```

Makes absolutely sure that no mistakes are made in this regard and is probably why it is recommended.

> What I don't understand is why do we need `exports` anyway since we can
>   perfectly work things out with using only `module.exports`.

As long as your code NEVER uses `exports`, you can just use `module.exports` and never worry about `exports`.  You do not NEED `exports`.  It was likely provided as a convenience, but as you have figured out that convenience can lead to bugs if misused.

> Why do we have exports anyway? Can someone explain to me the benefits
>   of using exports instead of module.exports?

`exports` was probably just provided as a typing convenience.  The only benefit to using `exports` over `module.exports` is a little less typing and perhaps a teeny performance difference as there is one less property lookup.  Personally I just pretend `exports` isn't there and I never use it.  I logically think of `module.exports` as the real location for exports so I just assign or modify there and there is never have a problem doing it that way.

---

**Here's the longer explanation.**

When a module is initialized, it is wrapped inside a function that looks like this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
    //contents from file1.js
    module.exports = '123;
});
```

This is where the definition of `module` and `exports` come from.  By default, `module.exports === exports` when this function is first executed and your module code starts to run.  But, `exports` is just a convenience here.  The real exports are in module.exports.  So, if you just do this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
    //contents from file1.js
    exports = {foo: 123};
});
```

That ends up not doing anything because `module.exports` will not be affected at all and that's where the real exports are.  But, if you do this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
    //contents from file1.js
    module.exports = {foo: 123};
});
```

Then, the real exports are indeed modified and your module will work properly, but as soon as you execute `module.exports = {foo: 123};`, you've made `module.exports` point to new object and it will now point at a different object than `exports` points to.  So, for total safety, some people recommend you do this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
    //contents from file1.js
    exports = module.exports = {foo: 123};
});
```

Then, both `exports` and `module.exports` always point at the same object.

---

If you NEVER use `exports` by itself, then you don't ever need to assign anything to it and you can just do this:

```
module.exports = {foo: 123};
```

And, there will be no issues at all.  But, you have to make sure that no code actually uses just `exports` if you've changed the object that `module.exports` points to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! This definitely clears it for me!