# How to parse functions bodies from a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I'm looking for a way to get a function declaration body by name from a string of js code. I'm in Nodejs environment.
Let's say I have some spaghetti.js file. I can read it into a string

```
const allJs = fs.readFileSync('spaghetti.js');
```

Now I need a function that receives that string and function name and returns a string with everything between `{ }`.

Something like this

```
allJs = 'let a=1; const b=[2, 3]; function cook(items){return items}; cook(b)';
parseFunction(allJs, 'cook');//'return items'
```

The complexity of input js is not limited.

I tried to find an npm module for that, but no luck.

Comment: What is the second parameter ("cook") of your `parseFunction` for?

Comment: If the complexity of your input js is not limited, you should specify which function bodies you want. All, just the first, a special one, even nested ones, class methods, etc ...?

Comment: @Jamiec that's a function name to look for in the input code

Comment: right, but your string input already includes a call to `cook`. POssibly you meant for that to be `return cook(b);` no?

Comment: @dsuckau, let's say I only want top level function declarations. No classes, methods etc.

Comment: See [JavaScript parser in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554519/javascript-parser-in-javascript)

Comment: @Jamiec, no, my function should return a string with a function declaration body. That's it. Invocations should be ignored.

Comment: Ok, not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve so i'll be off now :)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at an AST parser for Javascript:

http://esprima.org/

https://github.com/ternjs/acorn

That should be more safe than using RegExp or something.

Answer (score 0):

A `String` can be evaluated locally with the native [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method.  But remember, [`eval` is a form of evil](https://gist.github.com/lamberta/3768814)!

If the `parseFunction()` above is relying on [something like this](https://gist.github.com/lamberta/3768814) then the global [`Function constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is being used and the 'new' function is bound to the return value of that operation (and thus that return value itself needs to be called).

A simple way to achieve this might be to do something like this...

```
var funcString = 'var a = 1, b = 3;';
funcString += 'function summit(){return a + b;}';
funcString += 'return summit();';

function makeNewFunc(str) {
    return new Function(str);
}

var newFunc = makeNewFunc( funcString );

console.log('newFunc:',newFunc);
//-> newFunc: function anonymous()

console.log('newFunc():',newFunc());
//-> newFunc(): 4
```

This demonstrates how functions can be created and invoked from `String` snippets. (EDIT: [Turning something like that into a Node module is a simple matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888383/how-do-i-create-a-nodejs-module/35888384));

Hope that helped. :)

Comment: It seems you haven't understood my problem. I don't want to invoke anything. I just want to get a STRING representing a particular function's body. A simple text. You can think of it as some form of static code analysis.

Comment: @Andrey - I took your question, it's title, and the proposed `parseFunction` function to mean you were looking to, you know, parse a function from a string.  If you want to extract a string representation of a function's body then you're after "function decompilation" - see this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3179967/4746328