# Exporting variables and functions in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to export a set of global variables and functions from one Javascript file to another in nodejs.

From 
**node-js.include.js**

```
var GLOBAL_VARIABLE = 10;

exports.GLOBAL_VARIABLE = GLOBAL_VARIABLE;

module.exports = {

    add: function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }

};
```

into **test-node-js-include.js**:

```
var includes = require('./node-js-include');

process.stdout.write("We have imported a global variable with value " + includes.GLOBAL_VARIABLE);

process.stdout.write("\n and added a constant value to it " + includes.add(includes.GLOBAL_VARIABLE, 10));
```

but the variable; I get the following output:

```
We have imported a global variable with value undefined
 and added a constant value to it NaN
```

why isn't **GLOBAL_VARIABLE** exported?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [module.exports vs exports in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2 ways to fix this:

```
module.exports.GLOBAL_VARIABLE = GLOBAL_VARIABLE;

module.exports.add: function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

---

```
module.exports.GLOBAL_VARIABLE = GLOBAL_VARIABLE;

module.exports = { 
    add: function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 
    GLOBAL_VARIABLE: GLOBAL_VARIABLE
};
```