# Express middle ware difference between module.export and exports?

Tags: node.js, express

In some place i see people using "module.exports" and in others "exports",what is the difference ?

Comment: You can find an answer in here [module.exports vs exports in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7142924/4287861)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js

Answer (score 2):

exports is assigned to module.exports by default. So, they are essentially the same. Unless you reassign exports.

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_alias