# How to export and import two different function objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine-node

I use Jasmine-Node to test Javascript code.

How can one export two different function objects like Confusions1 and Confusions2 so that both are available in the Jasmine-Node test file?

My attempt looks like this:

```
// confusions.js
var Confusions1 = function() {};

Confusions1.prototype.foo = function(num) {
        // keep track of how many times `foo` is called
        this.count++;
}

module.exports = Confusions1;

// second function object

var Confusions2 = function() {};

Confusions2.prototype.foo = function() {
        var a = 2;
        this.bar(); 
};

Confusions2.prototype.bar = function() {
        return this.a;
}

module.exports = Confusions2;
```

And my Jasmine Test file:

```
// confusions.spec.js

var Confusion = require('./confusions.js');

describe("chapter 1, common misconception ", function() {
        describe("to assume `this` refers to the function itself: ", function() {
                var confusion = new Confusion();

                // some test code omitted


        });

        describe("to assume `this` refers to the function's scope", function() {
                var confusion = new Confusion();

                // test code omitted

        });
});
```

I want it so that Confusions1 and Confusions2 from `confusions.js` are both usable in the two nested describe blocks within `confusions.spec.js`

I assume that I have to somehow initialize different objects after requiring the file `var Confusion = require('./confusions.js');`
Something like `var confusion1 = new Confusions1(); var confusion2 = new Confusions2();` But how exactly (without splitting both Objects in two separate files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to have a module that behaves like a container of exported values, in another words you want to export two functions:

```
// foo.js
var Confusion1 = function() {}
var Confusion2 = function() {}
...
exports.Confusion1 = Confusion1
exports.Confusion2 = Confusion2
```

Wherever you need this module, you could require this stuff like:

```
// bar.test.js
var confusions = require('path-to-the-foo-file')
console.log(confusions.Confusion1)
console.log(confusions.Confusion2)
```

Also as it seems you should check how module system that you are using works in general, check this answer: [module.exports vs exports in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js/26451885#26451885)

Comment: Is there a way to quickly test your code without jasmine-node boilerplate? When i adjust my test with your approach i get an TypeError because the Confusion1/Confusion2 is undefined in the test...

Comment: What is node boilerplate? Nothing is related to any test framework, it is just about node module system. Create two modules from above and run `node bar.test.js`