# How to invoke function with arrow formed

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to invoke this function, in /file-name.js

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {       
    console.log('INFO: Hello World!!');
};
```

And this is how i am invoking it from /test/tester.js

```
var myFunc = require('../file-name.js');
myFunc(event, context, callback);
```

But i get this error:

```
TypeError: myFunc is not a function
```

PS: event, context and callback parameters was defined and are ok.
PS2: i can't change file-name.js. 
PS3: Finally work like this (thanks to @ankit31894):

```
var myFunc = require('../file-name.js');
myFunc.handler(event, context, callback)
```

Comment: You dont have to edit the question  to reflect how problem was solved, simply accepting the working answer will suffice

Comment: @ankit31894, i only want to put all code lines together, for futher reference. And yes, i will accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with arrow function. Do

```
myFunc.handler(event, context, callback);
```

Because you have exported an object which has a property called `handler` which in turn is your function.

In order to call function in the way you are calling you will have to export the function in `/file-name.js`

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (event, context, callback) => {       
    console.log('INFO: Hello World!!');
};
```

[Read difference between exports and module.exports in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7137397/1533609)