# Getting a TypeError: * is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm getting the following error in my server.js:

```
TypeError: routing is not a function
```

on

```
routing(app);
```

routing.js:

```
// JavaScript source code
var friends = require('./../controllers/friends.js');

module.export = function(app)
{...}
```

Comment: Did you `require` routing in server.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, you just exporting it wrong way (typo). You should wirte `module.exports` instead. The result you getting says that other module from which you call this module can't find it (you use the function which brings you `undefined`, and then you try to call something that is not a function, but just `undefined` value:

```
      // JavaScript source code
     var friends = require('./../controllers/friends.js');

     module.exports = function(app)
     {...}
```

For usage get information here:

[Stack Overflow - module.exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js)
[Node.JS Module Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)