# Error getting when executing nodejs through command prompt

Tags: node.js

I have the below code in Nodejs and tried to execute the same through command line as well as in browser, but getting "unexpected identifier" error.

```
var http = require('http'); 
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  response.end('<b>Running in server...</b>');
}).listen('3000', '127.0.0.1');
```

[image]

File name created is module3.js 
I am very new to nodejs. So can anyone please help me to resolve this. Thanks!!

Comment: It looks like you are not running the file itself but instead using the interactive environment.

Comment: D:\nodejs>node mudule3.js

Comment: I tried this way also and not working...

Answer (score 0):

If you like to run file, do it as usual for `shell` comman line (`interpreter file`):

```
D:\nodejs> node module3.js
```

If you like to work in `nodejs` command line, you need to load module by `require` and it will be loaded and evaluated:

```
D:\nodejs> node
> require('./module3')
```

If your module exports some function you may to call it:

```
D:\nodejs> node
> require('./module3')()
```

Check about exports [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7137397/2969544)

Comment: He's error indicates that it's something else - otherwise he would have got `module3 is not defined`

Comment: I edited the answer. The propblem solved by adding `./` at the begin of module pathname. If path name is absent in require then it search library with that name. If module path name is present then module loaded.

Comment: I just restarted my PC and found my code is working fine. I dont understand the actual problem.. Anyway thanks all for your valuable suggestions.