# Nodejs module without parameters

Tags: node.js

I am developing a Nodejs module, which is a function and returns an object with a function in a property. If I call the module without any parameter returns error (**Test is not a constructor**). If I call the module passing a parameter, even if it is empty, it works properly.

**Example #1**

*(App)*

```
//var test = require('./index.js')().Test; // Works properly
var test = require('./index.js').Test;

var sample = new test('text', function(newText) {
    console.log(newText);
});
```

*(Module)*

```
module.exports = function(options) {

    var bold = 0;
    var anotheModule = new anotherModule(options); //If the parameters are not defined, take the default.

    console.log('Check 1');

    return {
        Test: Test
    }

    function Test(text) {
        .....
    }
}
```

**Example #2**

*(Module)*

```
module.exports = function textChange(options) {

    var bold = 0;
    var anotheModule = new anotherModule(options); //If the parameters are not defined, take the default.

    console.log('Check 1');
}

textChange.prototype.Test = function(text) {
    .....
}
```

**Example #3**

*(Module)*

```
function textChange(options) {

    var bold = 0;
    var anotheModule = new anotherModule(options); //If the parameters are not defined, take the default.

    console.log('Check 1');
}

textChange.prototype.Test = function(text) {
    .....
}

module.exports = textChange;
```

**Example #4**

*(Module)*

```
function textChange(options) {

    var bold = 0;
    var anotheModule = new anotherModule(options); //If the parameters are not defined, take the default.

    console.log('Check 1');
}

Test = function(text) {
    .....
}

module.exports = textChange;
export.Test = Test;
```

I can't get the solution to work without passing parameters. I can't get the solution to work without passing parameters. If the application calls the module with parameters, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Test is not a constructor` that you're getting it is because you're using the `new` keyword on `undefined`. Since `Test` is undefined.

```js
const test = undefined;
try {
  new test();
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

In your example **#1** you're exporting a function that when executed returns an object containing `Test`, that's why you need to use `()` on the exported module.

---

In your example **#2** & **#3**, you're exporting a function (constructor), so it is the instance of `textChange` which has the `Test` method:

```
const textChange = require('./index.js');
new textChange().Test();
```

**Note:** Your example #2 will throw a `ReferenceError`, `textChange` is not defined since you're assigning it directly to `module.exports`, so it should be:

```
module.exports = function textChange(options) {

    var bold = 0;

    console.log('Check 1');
}

module.exports.prototype.Test = function(text) {
    /* ... */
}
```

---

In your last example, the last line: `export` should be `exports` but it won't do what you're expecting.

What's being exported it's `module.exports`, which is a function, `textChange` to be precise, so `Test` will never be available outside of that module.

```
var test = require('./module.js');
console.log(test.Test); // undefined
```

Check this question: [module.exports vs exports in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js)

---

I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but if you want

```
var test = require('./index.js').Test;
```

You should export an object containing `Test` property.

**Module**

```
module.exports = {

    Test(text) {
        /* ... */
    }

}
```

or

```
function Test(text) {
    console.log('Text: ', text);
}


module.exports.Test = Test;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and concise response. And if I need to pass the parameters to another module? I'm modifying the main message.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve, can you provide an example?