# what the difference in the export method of nodejs

Tags: node.js

Now, there are several method to export of nodejs, but what the difference between them.
  Like `module.exports`, `exports`, `export`, `export default`.

Comment: [the difference between module.exports and exports ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js),