# Node\Express - "TypeError: require(...) is not a function" or app is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, module

I keep getting this error message after refactoring my code into separate js files. I have tried numerous different methods based on SO posts but nothing seems to work, I either get this error or the app variable is `undefined` in my controller.

I am a complete Node novice so if someone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful!

Node  version: v6.17.0

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const controller = require('./plate-controller');

module.exports.app = app;
```

controller

```
const plateService = require('./plate-service');

var app = require('./app').app;
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.controller = function(app) {
    app.get('/plates/:plate_id', function (req, res) {
        return plateService.getPlateById(req, res);
    });

    app.get('/plates/search/:plate', function (req, res) {
        return plateService.search(req, res);
    });

    app.get('/plates/current-plates', function (req, res) {
        return plateService.getCurrentPlates(req, res);
    });

    app.get('plates/prefix-plates', function (req, res) {
        return plateService.getPrefixPlates(req, res);
    });
};
```

This gives undefined and trying to call like `require('..')()` always give the `is not a function` error.

When printing out the controller variable to the console it actually doesnt look as I thought it would, a function, rather its a function inside an object so I suppose that is the cause of the `require(...) is not a function`.

`{ controller: [Function] }`

Comment: try this module.exports = {app:app};

Comment: For this I get app undefined

Answer (score 1):

When `require` is called, `module.exports` is returned. `export` is not returned.

instead of using `exports.controller` use `module.exports.controller` like this:

```
module.exports.controller = function(app) {
app.get('/plates/:plate_id', function (req, res) {
    return plateService.getPlateById(req, res);
});

app.get('/plates/search/:plate', function (req, res) {
    return plateService.search(req, res);
});

app.get('/plates/current-plates', function (req, res) {
    return plateService.getCurrentPlates(req, res);
});

app.get('plates/prefix-plates', function (req, res) {
    return plateService.getPrefixPlates(req, res);
});
};
```

For more information, you can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js#answer-26451885)

Comment: When I tried what you suggested, which I had already tried last night I got the same issue. The only way I could get it to work was in the example I pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have worked this out now so in case this saves someone else some pain then here is the way I did it, I had followed a tutorial to get this far and I didnt realise that the function would be wrapped in an object when it was returned.

If there is a better way to do this then please let me know.

```
const controllerExports = require('./plate-controller');
controllerExports.controller(app);
```