# How to get Jest to see the functions I am writing for MongoDB Stitch?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mongodb-stitch

I am trying out Stitch, a serverless/hosted JavaScript environment from MongoDB. My main purpose is to help me learn modern JavaScript, but I am trying to write a useful app as well.

I have written the following function, and saved it in my Stitch app. I believe this follows the documented way to write functions in Stitch, and I have tested it from the Stitch administration console:

```
exports = function(query){
  const http = context.services.get("HTTP");
  const urlBase = context.values.get("stackOverflowApiUrl");
  const options = [
    'order=desc',
    'sort=activity',
    'site=stackoverflow',
    'q=' + encodeURIComponent(query),
    'user=472495',
    'filter=!--uPQ.wqQ0zW'
  ];

  return http
    .get({ url: urlBase + '?' + options.join('&') })
    .then(response => {
      // The response body is encoded as raw BSON.Binary. Parse it to JSON.
      const ejson_body = EJSON.parse(response.body.text());
      return ejson_body.total;
    });
};
```

This code is pretty simple - it obtains an `http` object for making external API fetches, and obtains a configuration value for a URL `urlBase` to contact (resolving to `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts`) and then makes a call to the Stack Overflow Data API. This runs a search query against my user and returns the number of results.

So far so good. Now, I want to call this function locally, in Jest. To do this, I have installed Node and Jest in a local Docker container, and have written the following test function:

```
const callApi = require('./source');

test('Simple fetch with no user', () => {
    expect(callApi('hello')).toBe(123);
});
```

This fails, with the following error:

```
~ # jest
 FAIL  functions/callApi/source.test.js
  ✕ Simple fetch with no user (3ms)

  ● Simple fetch with no user

    TypeError: callApi is not a function

      2 | 
      3 | test('Simple fetch with no user', () => {
    > 4 |     expect(callApi('hello')).toBe(123);
        |            ^
      5 | });
      6 | 

      at Object.<anonymous>.test (functions/callApi/source.test.js:4:12)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.418s
Ran all test suites.
```

(In fact I was expecting it to fail, since it contains a global object `context` that Jest does not have access to. I will work out how to mock that later, but for now Jest cannot even see the function at all).

I suspect I can see the reason - in the Jest introduction docs, one has to do this for the SUT:

```
module.exports = function() { ... }
```

However the Stitch docs seem to require functions to be defined as:

```
exports = function() { ... }
```

I do not have a background in JavaScript to understand the difference. I could try `module.exports` in Stitch, but I would rather not, since this would either not work now, or cause a breakage in the future. Can Jest be instructed to "see" bare `exports` without the `module` prefix?

Incidentally, I have picked Jest because it is popular, and because some of my JavaScript colleagues vouch for it. However, I am not wedded to it, and would be happy to use something else if it is known to be better for Stitch development.

### Update

Following the useful answer from jperl below, I find that the following construction is not possible in Stitch:

```
module.exports = exports = function() {}
```

I also cannot do this:

```
exports = function() {}
module.exports = exports
```

If I try either, I get the following error:

> runtime error during function validation

So it looks like I have to get Jest to work without `module.exports`, or create a glue file that imports the `exports` version into `module.exports`, with the main file being used by Stitch, and the glue importer being used by Jest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js). And you're right in thinking it has to do with `modules.exports` vs `exports`. The thing is that `module.exports` and `exports` first point to the same thing. So something like this works:

```
//modify the same object that modules.exports is pointing to
exports.a = {}
exports.b = {}
```

but this won't:

```
exports = {}
```

Why? Because now `exports` points to something else than `module.exports` so what you're doing has no effect at all.

### Update

Following some updates in the comments, we came to the view that Stitch does not seem to support the export format that Jest requires.

Comment: Ah, thanks jperl! I wonder if my question is close enough to your linked question, I wonder if it could be called a duplicate. I was expecting the answer to be an implementation-specific oddity in Stitch, to be honest, and given that Stitch is a lesser-spotted beastie on Stack Overflow, I did not think it was possible that an answer could exist already.

Comment: "Because now exports points to something else than module.exports so what you're doing has no effect at all" - indeed, but Stitch can still import it. I wonder if this is because `exports` is read locally in the Stich environment, rather than being fetched by `require`?

Comment: I have updated the question to explain that `module.exports` is not accepted by Stitch. Is there some way that Jest can use a bare `exports`, short of me writing a test bootstrap that "pre-compiles" the tests to include the `module.` prefix?

Comment: @halfer Oh, interesting! That's a peculiar case. I'm guessing that module isn't defined at all and exports is not an alias of module.exports.

Comment: @halfer could you try adding `if (!module) module = {}; module.exports = exports`?

Comment: Thanks, suggestions of things to try are appreciated. Unfortunately I get the same response from the Stitch UI: `runtime error during function validation`. I wonder if they have a naive regex filter that only allows the narrow `exports = function() { }` format.

Comment: @halfer I've just read this: Require statements must appear inside a function declaration, not outside it. Stitch does not currently support statements in the global scope.

Comment: Thanks @jperl. I have a dim idea of what that means. In the terms that a non-JS person can understand, I think that means that Stitch won't bend to my requirements. Can I modify Jest configuration instead? I am minded to write a shell script to copy-and-modify all the tests, so that I can move forward. It is less than elegant, but if needs must `:=)`.

Comment: @halfer I mean, that's probably why you get an error whenever you try to add anything outside the function ('Stitch does not currently support statements in the global scope'). You're out of luck :D. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: No problem - and thank you. I will get my Bash script hacking hat on, and will see if Jest supports a pre-test bootstrap, so I can create exportable functions prior to Jest running the main tests.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addendum to jperl's answer, to show how I got Jest working while respecting Stitch's limitations.

Firstly, it is worth noting how a Stitch application is laid out. This is determined by the import/export format.

```
auth_providers/
functions/
    function_name_1/
        config.json
        source.js
    function_name_2/
        config.json
        source.js
    ...
services/
values/
```

The `config.json` file is created by Stitch remotely, and is obtained through a export. This contains ID information to uniquely identify the function in the same folder.

I believe it is common JavaScript practice to mix tests with source code, so I am following that style (I am new to modern JS, and I confess I find this style untidy, but I am running with it nevertheless). Thus I add a `source.test.js` file in each function folder.

Finally, since there is a discrepancy between what Stitch requires and what Jest requires, I have written a script to create a source code file under `_source.js` in each function folder.

So, each folder will contain these files (the underscore files will probably be ignored by Git, as they will always be generated):

```
_source.js
config.json
source.js
source.test.js
```

In order to create the underscored copies, I am using this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Copy all source.js files as _source.js
for f in $(find functions/ -name source.js); do cp -- "$f" "$(dirname $f)/_$(basename $f)"; done

# Search and replace in all _source.js files
for f in $(find functions/ -name _source.js); do sed -i -e 's/exports =/module.exports =/g' $f; done
```

A bit hacky perhaps, but it works!