# How does exports object reference module.exports in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, module.exports

In Node.js, module object contains an exports property, that is an empty object. This object can be used to reference module.exports (*exports.a = "A";*), unless it is reassigned (*module.exports = "one";*).

My question is - what makes this exports object reference module.exports?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module.exports vs exports in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CommonJS modules are actually pretty simple: you take all the code in a file, and just wrap it in a function. Execute the function, and return the value of `module.exports` after execution to the caller.

You can see this function's header in the [node.js source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L191):

> ```
> const wrapper = [
>   '(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ',
>   '\n});'
> ];
> ```

The wrapper is applied to the code in the `require`'d file and then called [like this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L1191-L1204):

> ```
>   const exports = this.exports;
>   const thisValue = exports;
>   const module = this;
>   if (requireDepth === 0) statCache = new Map();
>   if (inspectorWrapper) {
>     result = inspectorWrapper(compiledWrapper, thisValue, exports,
>                               require, module, filename, dirname);
>   } else {
>     result = compiledWrapper.call(thisValue, exports, require, module,
>                                   filename, dirname);
>   }
> ```

As you can see it's pretty straightforward. `const exports = this.exports`, and then `exports` is passed as an argument to the wrapper function - thus they initially point to the same value, but if you reassign either then they no longer do.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! That explains it very well.