# Why can I reassign module.exports as a function but can't do the same with just exports in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

AFAIK, `module.exports` and `exports` are available through *hidden* arguments available to any file via a wrapping function and point to the same object in node.js.

If I do this:

```
exports.foo = 'foo';
  module.exports.bar = 'bar';
```

both `foo` and `bar` will be accessible to the file that imports it.

Also, I can do this:

```
 module.exports = ()=>{}
```

But I can't do this:

```
 exports = () =>{}
```

Why's that? If one is allowed to be overridden so should be the other as both point to the same object. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module.exports vs exports in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js)

Comment: @bigless Went though this. But I'm still trying to wrap my head around why one is allowed to be overridden while the other is not when both points to the same object?