# Can access module property with square bracket notation but not with dot property notation

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

I'm exporting a function from a controller file:

```
import adminSaveSnippet from './admin/adminSaveSnippet';
exports.saveSnippet = adminSaveSnippet;
```

I am importing the function into my routing file:

```
import * as express from 'express';
const adminRouter = express.Router();
import * as admin from '../controllers/adminControllers';

adminRouter.put('/save/snippet', admin['saveSnippet']);

export default adminRouter;
```

I can access the `saveSnippet` function in `admin` via `admin['saveSnippet']` but when I use dot notation  `admin.saveSnippet` I get the following error:

```
src/routes/admin.ts:5:40 - error TS2339: Property 'saveSnippet' does not exist on type 'typeof import(".../src/controllers/adminControllers")'.
```

I am not really sure what is going on. I am not using any [irregular identifiers](https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/) and I have tried several different ways of exporting the function (e.g., `import { saveSnippet } from '../controllers/adminControllers'`) but still get the same error.

For completeness here is my adminSaveSnippet file:

```
export default function adminSaveSnippet (_req, res) {

  console.log('here');
  res.send('saved').status(200);
}
```

Comment: did you tried `module.exports.saveSnippet = adminSaveSnippet` ?

Comment: this might help to understand the difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js

Comment: `module.exports.saveSnippet` does not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably just a TypeScript syntax issue.

In your adminControllers.ts file, try the `export` syntax, like you have done in your adminSaveSnippet file, instead of the CommonJS `exports`:

```js
export {
  adminSaveSnippet as saveSnippet
}
```

Comment: Seems to have worked. Just changed it to `export {
  adminSaveSnippet as saveSnippet
}`