# I can't module.exports more than 1 function

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, module.exports

If I do the following:

```js
// at the end of database.js
module.exports = mongoConnect;
module.exports = getDb;

// app.js
const mongoConnect = require('./util/database').mongoConnect;
mongoConnect();
```

I get the error: `ERROR: mongoConnect is not a function`.

But if I instead export them like this:

```js
// at the end of database.js
module.exports = {
    mongoConnect,
    getDb,
};
```

Then running `console.log(mongoConnect)` in `app.js` gives the following:

```js
{
    mongoConnect: [Function: mongoConnect],
    getDb: [Function: getDb],
}
```

and `app.js` can use `mongoConnect` just fine.

Why can't I use the first format?

Comment: The second line is overwriting the ``exports`` containing ``mongoConnect``

Comment: For the same reason why `x` cannot be both `1` and `2` when you do `var x; x = 1; x = 2;`.

Comment: Even though this question shows some lack of basic JS knowledge, I'm not sure it's a reason to downvote it. Seems like a genuine question to me, worth answering.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4642212). The tooltip on the downvote arrow says _“This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful”_. I can’t spot any research by the OP.

Comment: fair enough @SebastianSimon, but i did some research. i had this problem because in a tutorial it worked for him doing 2 times module.exports and not for me, that's why i tilted. but i think under the hood he change it

Comment: @feedback Which tutorial?

Comment: @SebastianSimon is in udemy, but after watching the video from the beginning he changed it. i was just tired ahahah sorry to bother you, and others, i really appreciate this fast-help. love this comunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the exports, thus only the last value is saved. Besides, when directly assigning `exports`, then `require('...')` will be that exact exports.

Your second example is how you're meant to export multiple values:

```js
// module
module.exports = {
    mongoConnect,
    getDb,
};

// other module
const module = require('./module');
module.getDb(...);

// or alternatively
const { getDb } = require('./module');
getDb(...);
```

Comment: ok thanks sir, im new in nodejs. this helped me alot to 
 understand what is happening :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js/26451885#26451885

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer as the solution to your question.