# Why does Node pass in the exports argument on top of the module argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js

It is known that each module in Node.js is wrapped in a function, where 5 arguments are passed in (i.e. `exports`, `module`, `require`, `__filename`, `__dirname`) and the `module.exports` object is returned.

Since `exports` is just an alias for `module.exports`, is there a reason why both module and exports are listed as 2 separate arguments? Wouldn't it be better if it was just `module` object being passed in? This would prevent the exports object from being unintentionally reassigned if the user were to do a top-level reassignment (e.g. `exports = {x: 5}`).

In terms of design, is it simply for the ease of accessing the exports object? I feel like I'm missing out something here.

I couldn't find this question being answered, but I'm happy to be redirected to an existing one.

```js
// function (exports, module, require, __filename, __dirname) {

const a = 1;
console.log(a);

// return module.exports;
// }
```

Comment: [Googling “site:stackoverflow.com node.js exports vs module.exports”](//google.com/search?q=site%253Astackoverflow.com+node.js+exports+vs+module.exports) gets [module.exports vs exports in Node.js](/q/7137397/4642212). Also, this isn’t truly about “language design”, since Node.js is not a language and this particular behavior is only how this particular JS environment decided to handle things.

Comment: Good read, I guess, but not specifically for this question. In that question there's  this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment50445513_26451885 which is quite close, but doesn't look... canonical.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js

Comment: Okay this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14424583/5267751 has a "more reasonable" explanation of the `exports` part.

Comment: Thanks @user202729 :) Looks like the answer is stating that the reason is due to `module.exports` not being CommonJS-like - but I would assume the con of accidentally reassigning `exports` outweigh the advantage of being in alignment with the standard.

Comment: If you think about it, it's not really breaking any standard, it's no different to `__dirname` been something extra in the node ecosystem, exports is just a reference to the existing standard, its not changed it.

Comment: @Keith No, in this case "the standard" is "use `exports`" (CommonJS standard), "breaking the standard" would be "use only `module.exports`".

Comment: @user202729  Your probably right, but the point still stands if you switch it around.  IOW: `module.exports`, doesn't break the commonjs spec, it's just something extra that node has exposed, like `__dirname` etc..

Answer (score 0):

As node.js document said:

It allows a shortcut, so that module.exports.f = ... can be written more succinctly as exports.f = .... However, be aware that like any variable, if a new value is assigned to exports, it is no longer bound to module.export

```
module.exports.hello = true; // Exported from require of module
exports = { hello: false };  // Not exported, only available in the module
```

When the module.exports property is being completely replaced by a new object, it is common to also reassign exports:

```
module.exports = exports = function Constructor() {
  // ... etc.
};
```

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#exports-shortcut

Comment: Thanks @HDM91, I'm aware of what it does but I'm not sure why exporting has to be made available in 2 ways, apart from the fact that `exports` is more succinct.