# What is the difference between "module.exports" and "exports.module" in java script

Tags: javascript

I have created a Model named 'Product' and the below code in there

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = require('../util/database');

const Product = sequelize.define('product',{
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoincrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    price: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    imageUrl:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
});

exports.module = Product;
```

I am getting the below error

```
Product.create is not a function
```

If I replace `exports.module = Product;` with `module.exports = Product;`, It is working good.

Can anyone clarify what is the difference between the two

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`module.exports` is the property used to export values from a CommonJS module.

`exports` is a shorthand for `module.exports`.

`exports.module` is the same as `module.exports.module` which creates an value named `module` on the exported object.

---

So if you have:

```
module.exports = Product;
```

Then you would match it with:

```
const Product = require('./myModule');
```

---

But if you have:

```
exports.module = Product;
```

Then you would:

```
const myModule = require('./myModule');
const Product = myModule.module;
```

---

`exports.module` is, basically, a mistake and makes code confusing. Don't do that.