# Node.js "require" function and parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

When I do:

```
lib = require('lib.js')(app)
```

is `app` actually geting passed in?

in lib.js:

```
exports = module.exports = function(app){}
```

Seems like no, since when I try to do more than just `(app)` and instead do:

```
lib = require('lib.js')(app, param2)
```

And:

```
exports = module.exports = function(app, param2){}
```

I don't get `params2`.

I've tried to debug by doing:

```
params = {}
params.app = app
params.param2 = "test"

lib = require("lib.js")(params)
```

but in lib.js when I try to `JSON.stringify` I get this error:

```
"DEBUG: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"
```

Comment: What are the variables you're passing in? Are they declared and defined?

Comment: Did u figure this out? Likely a spelling error like in your description.   "params?2"

Answer (score 129):

When you call `lib = require("lib.js")(params)`

You're actually calling `lib.js` with one parameter containing two properties name `app` and `param2`

You either want

```
// somefile
require("lib.js")(params);
// lib.js
module.exports = function(options) {
  var app = options.app;
  var param2 = options.param2;
};
```

or

```
// somefile
require("lib.js")(app, param2)
// lib.js
module.exports = function(app, param2) { }
```

Comment: +1 for answering the part that the OP added in after my answer :\

Comment: @JimSchubert sorry mr schubert :(

Comment: And then to have actual exports from my nodejs code I have `module.exports  = function(options) { ....; return { fn1, fn2 }};`  This works though is there a better way?

Answer (score 21):

You may have an undefined value that you're trying to pass in.

Take for instance, `requires.js`:

```
module.exports = exports = function() {
   console.log('arguments: %j\n', arguments);
};
```

When you call it correctly, it works:

```
node
> var requires = require('./requires')(0,1,2,3,4,5);
arguments: {"0":0,"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5}
```

If you have a syntax error, it fails:

```
> var requires = require('./requires')(0,);
... var requires = require('./requires')(0,2);
...
```

If you have an undefined object, it doesn't work:

```
> var requires = require('./requires')(0, undefined);
arguments: {"0":0}
```

So, I'd first check to see that your object is defined properly (and spelled properly when you pass it in), then check that you don't have syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was that I forgot to change the number of arguments for one of the calls.

Comment: Now I understand how this works a bit better. My remaining question is now about the JSON error. Do most people just debug through the browser?

Comment: As far as I know, most people use `util.inspect` to inspect objects (this is done internally with `console.log`). You can also use node-inspector (see [article](http://howtonode.org/debugging-with-node-inspector) for video tutorial). node-inspector is the webkit inspector (like CTRL+SHIFT+J in Chrome) which listens to `node --debug`.

Comment: Why did you also assign a variable called `exports` in line `module.exports = exports =...` ?

Comment: @SohailSi This is a way to prevent any programmatic errors (like if someone binds a new object to both `exports` and `module.exports`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13622513/151445 for more details.

Comment: Thank you @JimSchubert for the educational comment.