# How to make the node.js require function in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

How can I make the node.js `require` function in pure JavaScript? I have searched the web for any solutions but I have found none.

Something along the lines of this:

```
function require(path){
    //Code
    return data;
}
```

Some of the posts I have already seen:

- [How does require() in node.js work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475792/how-does-require-in-node-js-work)
- [Node.js "require" function and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367850/node-js-require-function-and-parameters)

Comment: This looks interesting. Why is it necessary to implement the require function in pure JavaScript?

Comment: It entirely depends on how you're able to locate & load other scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommonJS functionality is implemented in the [Curl Library](https://github.com/cujojs/curl) As pointed out in other answers `RequireJS` follows the AMD spec which is different than Node's CommonJS `var foo = require('foo');` spec.

Curl Features at a glance:

- Loads AMD-formatted javascript modules in parallel
- Loads CommonJS/node modules (v1.1 when wrapped in a define())
- Loads CommonJS/node modules (unwrapped when using the cjsm11 loader)
- Loads non-AMD javascript files in parallel, too.
- Loads CSS files and text files in parallel
- Waits for dependencies (js, css, text, etc) before executing javascript
- Waits for domReady, if desired
- Allows for virtually limitless combinations of files and dependencies
- Tested with Safari 5+, IE6+, and recent Chrome, FF, Opera

[Browserify](http://browserify.org/) does not implement CommonJS straight out but rather transpiles your CommonJS style code into  a single `bundle.js` file which is included in the html.

[Webmake](https://github.com/medikoo/modules-webmake#modules-webmake%5C) seems to offer similar functionality to Browserify while also allowing for other file types.

In a nutshell CommonJS works like this:

1. Maintain a map of identifiers that correspond to loaded modules.
2. When a `require('lib')`is encountered, check the list to see if it has been loaded.  If the library has not been loaded (it's key is not in the library), load the script via XHRRequest.  If the library has been loaded, return the value that corresponds to the `key`.

This is why required modules are always singletons.

Answer (score 1):

RequireJS uses AMD loader, whereas node.js uses CommonJS pattern loading.

[Browserify](http://browserify.org/) allows you to wrap up all of your code in a build step so you can have `require()` statements in a browser.

To roll your own (which I do not suggest, as Browserify is already a battle-tested, popular library), you would have to map all of your modules on your own and load it upfront, or load them synchronously (as that's necessary for CommonJS spec), in a blocking (and undesirable) way.

Answer (score 1):

`code` in your function should contain full module resolution logic, which may not be that light and simple. You can check source code of `module` module which is responsible for that in node.js -> https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js

There are various tools which help you port CJS modules outside of node.js (they provide `require` function for you): Most popular is [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), but you can also check [Webmake](https://github.com/medikoo/modules-webmake#modules-webmake) (I'm the author).

Comment: Nice to see another option other than browserify.