# Why does require('../models/owners.js') have another adjacent parameters next to it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, require

```js
require('../models/owners.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

I don't understand the syntax of having `require(..something)(why?)` next to each other?

Comment: You are calling a constructor function for the module, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7367898/8678978
Are `sequelize` and `Sequelize` declared somewhere else in your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require('../models/owners.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

The above is (pretty much) equivalent to

```
const owners = require('../models/owners.js');
owners(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

However the second example results in a constant called `owners` as well.

Comment: `require('../models/owners.js')` returns a function, that you can store in a variable or even use right away