# How to have a file inherit exports in node.js / express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a folder in my express.js app containing three files:

```
// models/one.js
exports.One = function() { return 'one'; }

// models/two.js
exports.Two = function() { return 'two'; }

// models/three.js
exports.Three = function() { return 'three'; }
```

I'd like to be able to use it like this:

```
var db = require('./models');
doSomething(db.One, db.Two, db.Three);
```

In other words, **I want to group exports from multiple files in one variable**.

I know that by default that require statement will look for models/index.js. Is there anything I could put in index.js that will allow it to inherit the exports from the other files in the directory, such as (non-working psuedocode):

```
// models/index.js
exports = require('./one.js', './two.js', './three.js);
```

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Customizing existing Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884245/customizing-existing-module) for the solution.

Or you can load all the files in a directory, e.g.

**a.js:**

```
exports.a = 1;
```

**b.js:**

```
exports.b = 2;
```

**index.js:** (this will require all the `.js` files in the same directroy and bundle them to a single object)

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , path = require('path')
  , bundle = {}
  , i
  , k
  , mod;

fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(function(filename) {
  if (path.extname(filename) == '.js' &&
      path.resolve(filename) != __filename) {
    mod = require(path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, filename)));
    for (k in mod) {
      bundle[k] = mod[k];
    }
  }
});

module.exports = bundle;
```

requiring the directory you will see

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Comment: Note that since your using `readdirSync` this _must_ execute before the server boots

Comment: @Raynos Would you please elaborate the reason?

Comment: Blocking IO blocks. You don't block a running single threaded server. It's acceptable to use blocking IO for a boot time convenience or for utility scripts but everything has to be non blocking once your server is accepting TCP/HTTP input.