# Express error - TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting this error when I run npm start to run my express app.

```
TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
```

my **app.js** code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);



/// catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

my **index.js** code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET Hello World page. */
router.get('/helloworld', function(req, res) {
    res.render('helloworld', { title: 'Hello, World!' })
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am quirte new to using Node and express. I cant see where I have gone wrong. Can anybody see what my problem is?

Comment: do you have users also defined like index.js, maybe error is bacause of this

Comment: @TheJugadGuru I have users defined as users.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465850/typeerror-router-use-requires-middleware-function-but-got-a-object)

Comment: I think you have deleted the code `modules.export = router;` . In my case i had deleted content of one whole file.

Comment: @MattClaff Can you please accept [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34011640/5734311)?

Comment: As a side-note (this isn't really an answer to this question, but putting it here in case other google searches find it), if you've got a React app that's using an `src/setupProxy.js` file to call `createProxyMiddleware`, make sure you've set that up correctly.  That uses express behind the scenes, and in one case I helped debug, had an error where there was an arrow function with extra braces and no explicit `return`, so that failed.  (`const proxy = () => {createProxyMiddleWare({...})}; app.use('/endpoint', proxy())`... the outer braces on that first part needed removal.)

Answer (score 105):

I found the answer in the comments from [Kop4lyf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1894565/kop4lyf):

> check your users.js. It should also be exporting the router like
>   index.js, if you can try that.

However, this question was my top search result when I ran into this issue, so I am promoting to an answer.

---

The error is caused because one of your route modules is not being exported - meaning Express does not have access to it when it tries to identify all of your routes.

You can fix this by adding `module.exports = router;` to the end of each of your route files.

Example:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     //Do whatever...
});

module.exports = router;
```

More information about `module.exports` can be found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116960/what-do-module-exports-and-exports-methods-mean-in-nodejs-express) or the [offcial Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports).

Comment: That's worked for me! Actually we have to import router module

Comment: Thanks. This is the perfect answer for any newbie to get understand. It helped me.

Comment: Thank you @HPierce.
I did not exported router in two controllers. I did it on only one.
Now its fixed.

Answer (score 24):

I have fixed this by adding which i am using somewhere. So please check your all exports.

```
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use in routes

```js
exports default router
```

Your solution can be

```js
module.exports = router
```

Comment: Another solution is to use `require('./path/to/router).default` if you are using `exports default router`

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error , fixed it by replacing `app.use('view engine', 'ejs')` with  `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`.
For reference I used this webpage [Migrating from 3.x to 4.x](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x)

I didn't have to make any changes to either index.js or application.js. For more information on EJS one could refer [Using EJS with Express](https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express) and [Express 4.x API](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html)

Answer (score 4):

Your index.js file is fine you just have to create **users.js** and export it.

```
   let express = require('express');
   let router = express.Router();

  //Login Page - GET REQUEST
   router.get('/login',(req,res)=> {
      res.send('login page');
  })


  //Register Page - GET REQUEST
  router.get('/register',(req,res)=> {
     res.send('register page');
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
in every module  **export the router** and **keep one handler for the default 
path '/'**

// in index.js
const authRoute = require("./routes/authRoute");

app.use("/auth", authRoute);


// in authRoute.js

const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    // code
 });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when you forgot to export the module which uses the Router.

Your mentioned code works perfectly with some tweaks.

if your app.js is main/starting point of the app.

it should have

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

instead of

```
module.exports = app;
```

(optional)Generally index.js is used for starting point of app. Rename index.js as helloworld.js and change same at require statement

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
```

to

```
var routes = require('./routes/helloworld');
```

run this app using the following command

```
node app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you have checked all the solution than also having this error than check this one**

Another cause of having this error is calling a method which is not exist or not not exported.
In my case i am calling **login** method but i forgot to define them

I was trying to call this method

```
app.post('/api/login', db.login);
```

but i had forgot to create login method so i got this error. also try to check spelling mistake may be you might have typed wrong spell

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and then I discovered that I was missing this line in one of my controllers !

`return api;` //it might be `return router`for your code !

I added this line to my code and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Whew, my problem was that i was doing module.exports = { router } instead of module.exports = router

Comment: Please write in details

Comment: I was trying to export {router} < and it got exported as an OBJECT, that was why i was getting the error message, i just changed it to module.exports = router so it was just a functon not an object and it went through

Answer (score 0):

I found it after lot of struggle! as everything syntactically correct, nothing wrong with code that was written, it was due to the code that was not written yet! This could happen if you have implemented index.js but not yet users.js. However, you have already defined both lines
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
If you are eager to test index.js right away without waiting for users.js to be implemented. That's exactly when it errors out.

Answer (score 0):

if you are still facing this problem and try every solution then just replace router with  routes and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

For anybody using EJS:
In my case I was receiving this error as I used

```js
app.use("view engine","ejs")
```

instead of

```js
app.get("view engine","ejs")
```

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it by removing the `app.use(/users, users);`

I don't need this at the minute so maybe that is why it started breaking.

Comment: check your users.js. It should also be exporting the router like index.js, if you can try that.

Comment: Yeah I was missing  var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = router;