# meaning of module.exports= function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am taking first steps with node.js and obviously one of the first things i tried to do was exporting some data from a module, so i tried this simple case:

dummy.js:

```
var user = "rally";

module.exports = {
  user:user
};
```

and than required it from a different file like this:

```
var dummy = require('./dummy.js');
console.log(dummy.user); // rally
```

So far so good, every thing works, but now i dived into code where there is this definition in the beginning of the module:

```
module.exports = function(passport,config, mongoose) {}
```

and i don't understand whats the meaning of it and how can i work with it.
just for trying to understand i defined some variables inside this abstract function but couldn't get their value from any other file.
any idea how can i export variables from module defined like this..? so for example i could require this module and get the "Dummy" variable and use it in a different file

```
module.exports = function(passport,config, mongoose) {
var dummy = "Dummy";
}
```

Comment: Often wondered this myself. What exactly is `module.exports`? Have seen that alot in Gruntfile.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116960/what-do-module-exports-and-exports-methods-mean-in-nodejs?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js?rq=1

Comment: Also http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works exactly the same as the first one does, only that it exports a function instead of an object.

The module that imports the module can then call that function:

```
var dummy = require('./dummy.js');
dummy();
```

> any idea how can i export variables from module defined like this..?

Since functions are just objects, you can also assign properties to it:

```
module.exports = function(passport,config, mongoose) {}
module.exports.user = 'rally';
```

However I'd argue that this is less expected if a module directly exports a function. You are probably better off exporting the function as its own export:

```
exports.login = function(passport,config, mongoose) {}
exports.user = 'rally';
```

Answer (score 2):

**WHAT IS A MODULE?**

A module encapsulates related code into a single unit of code. When creating a module, this can be interpreted as moving all related functions into a file.

```
// dummy.js
var exports = module.exports = {};
```

The utility of `dummy.js` increases when its encapsulated code can be utilized in other files. This is achieved by using `exports`.

**HOW ARE THEY INVOKED?**

You could declare your functions outside of the module.exports block. Functions inside exports can be invoked exactly the same way as variables or any other object.

**EXAMPLE**

```
//dummy.js

var myVariable = "foo";
var myFunction = function(){
     //some logic
};

module.exports{

      myVariable : myVariable,
      myFunction : myFunction,

      myVariableTypeTwo : "bar",
      myFunctionTypeTwo : function () {
           //some logic
      }

}
```

We can now access the publicly available methods of dummy.js as a property from any js file.

```
var dummy = require('./dummy.js');

dummy.myVariable; //foo
dummy.myFunction();

dummy.myVariableTypeTwo; //bar
dummy.myFunctionTypeTwo();
```

**NOTE**

In the code above, we could have replaced module.exports with exports and achieved the same result. If this seems confusing, remember that exports and module.exports reference the same object.

Comment: `module.exports{`…`}` is invalid syntax.