# What is the difference between express framework "module.exports" and "exports"?

Tags: express

i am new to express framework.  I need to understand the differences between "module.exports" and "exports" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do "module.exports" and "exports.methods" mean in NodeJS / Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116960/what-do-module-exports-and-exports-methods-mean-in-nodejs-express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exports and module.exports reference the same object. Exports is a variable that lives on module.exports. **module.exports** encapsulates related code into a single unit of code i.e. any methods or variable defined inside the module.exports can be available in other files. Have a look to this for more clarity [more on module.exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116960/what-do-module-exports-and-exports-methods-mean-in-nodejs-express)