# require not working if not using destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

In my `nodejs`, I have a small `mongoose` module which `exports` the `model (User)`. When I require the module without using `destructuring` assignment and I create the new instance of the model using `new` operator, I get the `error` that the model is not a function. But if i use the `destructuring` assignment when I `require` the model, everything works fine. Not able to understand why.

**User.js** exports the **model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

exports.User = mongoose.model('User', {
    email:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 1,
        reuqired: true
    }
});
```

Below code throws error if I dont use destructuring operator on **line 2**:
**server.js**

```
const mongoose = require('../DB/mongoose');
const User = require('../Models/User');

console.log(typeof(User));

let user = new User({
    email: "sdfdsf"
});
```

**server.js** throws the below error:

```
let user = new User({
           ^

TypeError: User is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\javascript\nodePractice\ToDoApp\server\server.js:6:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:576:3)
```

> But If I use a `destructuring` assignment on `line 2`, it works all fine.
>   **server.js**:

```
const mongoose = require('../DB/mongoose');
const {User} = require('../Models/User');

console.log(typeof(User));

let user = new User({
    email: "sdfdsf"
});
```

Comment: Of course it does, those two are not equivalent?

Comment: Yeah... you're assigning an object that contains a `User` property to your `User` variable in `server.js` in the first case.

Comment: This may help: [What do “module.exports” and “exports.methods” mean in NodeJS / Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116960/what-do-module-exports-and-exports-methods-mean-in-nodejs-express)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
const {User} = require('../Models/User');
```

is equivalent to

```
const User = require('../Models/User').User;
//                                    ^^^^^
```

The module object that `require()` returns (the `exports` object that your module filled) does have a `.User` *property*. If you don't access that but try to use the module object as a constructor, it throws.

To be explicit, you might want to use

```
const userModule = require('../Models/User');

console.log(typeof userModule);
console.log(typeof userModule.User);

let user = new userModule.User({
    email: "sdfdsf"
});
```

Alternatively, if you insist on doing `const User = require('../Models/User');`, you can also make the constructor function the exported object by overwriting [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) instead of creating a property on it:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', {
    …
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are exporting an object that has a property called "User" that hosts the model. When importing it you need to specify what part of the file you want to import, or you need to later specify what property you want to use. You can still use

```
const User = require('../Models/User');
```

But you will need to call `User.User`, accessing `exports.User` later on:

```
let user = new User.User({ //call exports.User from User model file
    email: "sdfdsf"
});
```