# Understanding exports in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I don't think I quite understand how `exports` work in *Node.js*. In a bit of sample code, I noticed the `exports` object used in this manner:

```
exports = mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect(config.db.uri)
exports = Schema = mongoose.Schema
```

What is happening behind the scenes when you use `exports =` twice like that? Looks to me like "mongoose" should not be exported. I did this quick test:

```
var foo
  , bar

exports = foo = 'foo'
exports = bar = 'bar'

// reports 'bar' only
console.log(exports)
```

and the second test does overwrite the first export.

Comment: Yeah, that is strange.  Usually, you would expect a `exports.foo = 'foo'` etc.

Comment: It may be possible that mongoose.Schema points to mongoose.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure this out myself, and as best I can tell, all 3 lines do nothing. By setting the exports object, the global exports object is lost. So, nothing is getting exported out of this file. The other key thing is that those variables (mongoose & Schema) are getting defined to the global object.

This seems like a way to flag that these variables are going to be globals and this file doesn't export those via the module interface. I can't see any other reason to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess is the original author of that sample code is confused about `module.exports` vs `exports`. To use the `exports` object, you must add properties to it like this:

```
exports.size = 42;
```

If you re-assign the `exports` *variable* to a new object, you basically lose access to the global exports object that node.js provided for you. If you do this twice or three or N times, the effect is the same. It's useless. For example: mod_b.js

```
var realExports = exports;
realExports.height = 42;
var exports = {};
exports.weight = 43;
```

And in mod_a.js

```
var mod_b = require('./mod_b');
console.dir(mod_b);
```

Run `node mod_a.js` and you get:

```
{ height: 42 }
```

Notice `height` is there but `weight` is not. Now, what you *can* do is assign `module.exports` to be an object, and that is the object that will be returned when another module `require`s your module. So you will see things like.

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;
module.exports = {x: x, y: y};
```

Which will do what you expect. Here's some informative articles on the details.

[Node.js Module – exports vs module.exports](http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-exports-vs-module-exports.html)

[What is the purpose of NodeJS module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5311334/266795)

[Mastering Node](http://visionmedia.github.com/masteringnode/book.html)

Comment: That Mastering Node link was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to @Peter-Lyons answer, your example is valid, your test case is incorrect.

Exporting variables like this is not recommended, but by doing that, you are exposing this variables into a global namespace.

e.g. test0.js

```
'use strict';

var assert = require('assert');
var test1 = require('./test1');

assert(globalVar1 === 123);
assert(globalVar2.a === 123);
```

test1.js -- mind the missing `'use strict';`

```
exports = globalVar1 = 123;
exports = globalVar2 = {a:123};
```

Once again, it's valid, but not recommended.

Cheers.