# CoffeeScript Object Syntax: exports.index vs exports = {}

Tags: coffeescript, express

I find that

```
exports.index = (req, res) ->
  res.render "index",
    title: "Hello"
```

compiles to

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    return res.render("index", { title: "Hello" })
}
```

Something that works with ExpressJS. However, I thought that I could use:

```
exports = 
    index: (req, res) ->
        res.render "index",
            title: "Hello"
```

so that I wont have to type `exports.xxx` for all routes, but that compiles to

```
var exports;
exports = {
  index: function(req, res) {
    return res.render("index", {
      title: "Hello"
    });
  }
};
```

which doesn't appear to work with ExpressJS, why?

```
Error: In /labs/Projects/jiewmeng/routes/index.coffee, Parse error on line 1: Unexpected '{'
    at Object.parseError (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/parser.js:477:11)
    at Object.parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/parser.js:554:22)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:43:20
    at Object..coffee (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:19:17)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/labs/Projects/jiewmeng/server.coffee:6:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/labs/Projects/jiewmeng/server.coffee:74:4)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding exports in NodeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627044/understanding-exports-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [this answer explaining module.exports vs exports = foo vs exports.foo = bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9714474/266795)

In short, if you assign a local variable named `exports` to a brand new object, you cannot assign properties to the "real" `exports` object, and thus your code doesn't work as expected. You can either A) assign an object to `module.exports` or B) assign properties to the existing `exports` object.

One pattern that works nicely in CoffeeScript is this:

```
module.exports = {
  SomeClass
  someFunction
  someObject
}
```

Comment: So can I say my method overrides all existing exports? Then if I use module.exports, it will "extend" the existing exports variable?

Comment: No, if you do `exports.property = foo` you "extend" the exports object. Doing `exports = bar` is a mistake/bug and won't have any effect on the properties exported by your module. Doing `module.exports = foo` lets you export a brand new object as opposed to the empty object node.js provides for you.