# Nodejs module exports usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In a sample application I saw a module with a code like this:

```
exports = mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect(config.db.uri)
exports = Schema = mongoose.Schema
```

Can someone explain what the above code means? After these three lines I can see that mongoose and Schema functions can be called from anywhere in the application but I can't get the logic behind this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding exports in NodeJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627044/understanding-exports-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

> `exports = mongoose = require('mongoose')`

This creates a variable called `moongoose` and sets it to be equal to `require('mongoose')`.

> `mongoose.connect(config.db.uri)`

This starts a connection with a database.

> `exports = Schema = mongoose.Schema`

This makes the module export `require('mongoose').Schema` for whatever reason.

This could be more simply written as:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect(config.db.uri)
exports = Schema = mongoose.Schema
```