# How to separate the routes and models from app.js using NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating an app using Node and Express. However, I can see it'll soon become difficult to manage all the routes that are placed inside `app.js`. I  have placed all my models in a subdirectory `/models`.

Here's my app current structure:

```
app.js
models
  -- products
  -- customers
  -- ...
public
views
node_modules
```

In `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    user = require('./routes/user'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    EmployeeProvider = require('./models/employeeprovider').EmployeeProvider,
    Products = require('./models/products').Products,
    Orders = require('./models/orders').Orders,
    Customers = require('./models/customers').Customers,
    checkAuth = function(req, res, next) {
      if (!req.session.user_id) {
        res.send('You are not authorized to view this page');
      } else {
        next();
      }
    };

var app = express();
```

Then some configuration like `port`, `views` directory, rendering engine, etc.

Further down `app.js` I've got the routes:

```
app.get('/product/edit', auth, function(req, res) {
  Products.findAll(function(error, prds) {
    res.render('product_edit', {
      title: 'New Product',
      products: prds
    });
  });
});
```

At the top I'm assigning the contents of `models/products.js` to a variable, all works fine. However keeping all routes inside `app.js` is not ideal. But if I move the routes to `routes/product.js` and load the `Products` models:

```
var prod = require('../models/products.js');
```

I get an error saying that object has no method `findAll`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I remove the routes from `app.js`?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38718561/1153703

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As of express 4.x `Router` is added to support your case.

> A router object is an isolated instance of middleware and routes. You can think of it as a “mini-application,” capable only of performing middleware and routing functions. Every Express application has a built-in app router.

Example from [expressjs site](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router):

```
// routes/calendarRouter.js

var express  = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// invoked for any requested passed to this router
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // .. some logic here .. like any other middleware
  next();
});

// will handle any request that ends in /events
// depends on where the router is "use()'d"
router.get('/events', function(req, res, next) {
  // ..
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then in app.js:

```
// skipping part that sets up app

var calendarRouter = require('./routes/calendarRouter');

// only requests to /calendar/* will be sent to our "router"
app.use('/calendar', calendarRouter);

// rest of logic
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `app.use('/calendar', require('./routes/x'));`?

Comment: Sure @Brennen, modified to make it clearer. Before I skipped the part where `router` was `required`.

Comment: looks like the calendarRouter.js file is missing some export ?

Comment: why module.exports=router is missing from calenderRouter.js file ?

Answer (score 33):

Since I don't like repetition, here's what I do:

```
// app.js
//...
var routes = requireDir('./routes'); // https://www.npmjs.org/package/require-dir
for (var i in routes) app.use('/', routes[i]);
//...
```

And each file in routes is like:

```
// routes/someroute.js
var express  = require('express');
var router   = express.Router();

router.get('/someroute', function(req, res) {
    res.render('someview', {});
});

module.exports = router;
```

This way you can avoid long repetitive lists like this one:

```
app.use('/'           , require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/repetition' , require('./routes/repetition'));
app.use('/is'         , require('./routes/is'));
app.use('/so'         , require('./routes/so'));
app.use('/damn'       , require('./routes/damn'));
app.use('/boring'     , require('./routes/boring'));
```

---

**Edit:** these long examples assume each route file contains something like the following:

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // ...
    next();
});
module.exports = router;
```

All of them could be mounted to "root", but what for them is "root", is actually a specific path given to `app.use`, because you can mount routes into specific paths (this also supports things like specifying the path with a regex, Express is quite neat in regards to what you can do with routing).

Comment: This seems like quite a nice idea but as I'm new to Node.js and Express I have a question. I see that you're saving the hassle of writing each individual route (/repetition, /is, etc.) but won't `app.use('/', routes[i]);` only set the required route on the '/' route? The long example you gave in the end is different, i.e. it's `app.use('/route', require('./routes/route'));`. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @DarrylYoung Tried to clear it up, see if it makes more sense now :)

Comment: great answer! tried to figure out what i did wrong with `module.exports.router` and you put me in good track with `module.exports = router;`

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get why this works (but i get how @Ivar Calendar answer). What if the URL is /calendar and in the Calendar route i have only set router.get('/', ...)? Can you elaborate on how app.use('/', ...) works? Thanks!

Comment: @Fernando each route is defined and exported in a file in the routes folder. each file there is required and `app.use`d directly. See it like this: when you call `app.use('/', someRoute)` the root of `someRoute` is merged on the root of the app, so if the route was defined as mounted at '/calendar', you'll now have a route like that in your app. You can create fresh routes with `express.Router()` and mount them later (not only on '/' but any path) with `app.use()`

Answer (score 21):

I can suggest you this file structure (according to [Modular web applications with Node.js and Express from tjholowaychuk](http://vimeo.com/56166857)):

```
app.js
   modules
      users
         index.js
         model.js
      users-api
         index.js
      static-pages
         index.js
```

`user-api` and `static-pages` export expressjs applications, you can easily mount them in app.js.
In `users` module you can describe some Data Access operations and all methods about manipulating with the User entity (like create, update etc.). Our API module will use all these methods.

And here is sample code of app.js file (without common express stuff, only mounting routes from different modules):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// mount all the applications
app.use('/api/v1', require("user-api"));
app.use(require("static-pages"));

app.listen(3000);
```

To use your modules this way you must start your app like this `NODE_PATH=modules node app.js` (i put this line to package.json file in scripts section).

Here is sample code of `users` module:

**index.js**

```
User = require("./model");

module.exports = {
    get: function(id, callback) {
        User.findOne(id, function(err, user) {
           callback(err, user);
        });
    },
    create: function(data, callback) {
        // do whatever with incoming data here
        data = modifyDataInSomeWay(data);
        var newUser = new User(data);
        newUser.save(function(err, savedUser) {
            // some logic here
            callback(err, savedUser); 
        });
    }
};
```

**model.js** (with Mongoose stuff for example of course!)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new Schema({
    firstname   : {type: String, required: false},
    lastname    : {type: String, required: false},
    email       : {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', User);
```

And example of `user-api` module (here is the main part of the answer about separating routes and models).

```
var users = require("users");

var express = require("express");
var app = module.exports = express(); // we export new express app here!

app.post('/users', function(req, res, next) {
    // try to use high-level calls here
    // if you want something complex just create another special module for this
    users.create(req.body, function(err, user) {
        if(err) return next(err); // do something on error
        res.json(user); // return user json if ok
    });
});
```

And example of `static-pages`. If you are not going to build a kind of REST interface you may simply create several modules that will render pages only.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = module.exports = express(); // we export new express app here again!

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {user: req.user});
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
    // get data somewhere and put it in the template
    res.render('about', {data: data});
});
```

Of course you can do whatever you want with modules. The main idea about expressjs is to use a lot of small apps instead of single one.

About nodejs modules you can read [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9714474/1274503) and [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see the logic of separating users and users-api... the api stuff should be in the users dir, otherwise that will get convoluted quick

Comment: @AlxVallejo thanks for comment! You are absolutely right in context of this question but not in context of application where i used separate folders for models and APIs (it is more complex then this super simple example).

Comment: from where this "users" came from ?

`var users = require("users");`  is from ?

Comment: @duardbr `users` is a module for working with Users entities (you can find an example in my post). It can be as simple as get/create/update/remove or contain any complex logic and methods.