# Unable to set separate route files in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webstorm

I want to separate my login route from default `app.js` and `route/index.js` files but I'm not getting `error 404` Not Found while executing `localhost:3000/login`

I know this questions has been asked already before and I've followed other answers on StackOverflow but not getting why I'm getting error.

Stack overflow question I followed:
[How to separate routes on Node.js and Express 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923365/how-to-separate-routes-on-node-js-and-express-4)

I'm not getting why I'm getting this error.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var session = require('express-session');

var mongodb = require('./mongoDB');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var login = require('./routes/login'); //including login.js

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
    app.use(session({
    name: 'mysession',
    secret: 'some_secret',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: true, cookie: {
      secure: true
    }}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/login', login);

mongodb.connectDatabase;

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**route/login.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
   res.send('exec');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**localhost:3000/login**

```
Not Found
404
Error: Not Found
    at /home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/app.js:44:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
    at next (/home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (/home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
    at router (/home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /home/jatin/Drive/OpenSource/sessionManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little confusing, but when you use:

```
app.use('/login', login);
```

You are nesting all routes defined in `login` under the `/login` namespace. You can probably currently access the route at `/login/login`

Change your `login.js` to:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('exec');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then `/login/` will correctly be routed to the `/` route of the `login` namespace

Comment: Thanks @Rob M. for help