# Express middleware that adds more middleware and routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have a Node/Express app that looks like this:

```js
app.use(foo)
...
app.get('/foo/bar', ...)
...
app.get('/index', ...)
```

And I want to extract the middleware and the routes so that now I can do:

```js
app.use(myMiddlewareAndRoutes)
...
app.get('/index', ...)
```

So that `myMiddlewareAndRoutes` adds the middleware `foo` and the route `'/foo/bar'` that belongs to it.

#### How can I do this?

Comment: It does not make sense that middleware adds more routes.  Middleware is called repeatedly on lots of incoming requests.  You do not want it adding routes over and over and over again.  What I would suggest is that you back up a couple steps and describe your actual problem rather than only describing your attempted solution to a problem you haven't fully described.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to separate routes on Node.js and Express 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923365/how-to-separate-routes-on-node-js-and-express-4)

Comment: Perhaps you want to use a separate router that has the `/foo` and `/foo/bar` routes on it and you can then `app.use(router)` in one statement.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About birds')
})

module.exports = router
```

```js
var birds = require('./birds')

// ...

app.use('/birds', birds)
//or if you need it on root level
app.use('/', birds)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a separate `Router` object then add it as a middleware with the `.use()` function.

In the `foo.js` file I'm creating a new router and exporting it:

**foo.js**

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();

router.get('/bar', (req, res, next) => {
    return res.send('bar');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then importing it in the `index.js` file to add it as a middleware:

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const foo = require('./foo.js');

const app = express();

app.use('/foo', foo);

app.get('/index', ...)
```

Now every route you define in `foo.js` will use the `/foo` prefix like `/foo/bar`.