# Appcelerator and CommonJS modules (caching and circular references)

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, circular-reference, commonjs

Here's the thing:

I'm using the CommonJS way of making my mobile (iPhone/Android) application modular. No surprise there. But there's one thing that I just can't get my head around.

CommonJS lets me create STATIC private variables, which lets me create singletons at ease. This, I think at least, is because the contents of a file that gets `require()`d is read only once and then the exports object (which is initialized only once) is returned every time.

But when I create a circular reference as seen below, the code inside the included module is executed every time.

**Wait...**
Funny thing is, while I'm writing this question, I suddenly realise that none of the calls to `require()` finish before the next one starts (hence the stack overflow demonstrated below).

Any thoughts on whether I'm on track or not? It's past 5 AM over here, so all bets are off as far as I'm concerned :D.

**EXAMPLES:**

See this piece of code, it defines a singleton:

```
/* Singleton.js */

exports.getSingleton = getSingleton;

function getSingleton(name) {
  if (!instance) {
    instance = new Thing(name);
  }

  return instance;
}

function Thing(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var instance;
```

I `require()` this file as such:

```
var theFirstThing = require('Singleton').getSingleton('first');
Ti.API.info('first: ' + theFirstThing.name)

var possiblyAnotherOtherThing = require('Singleton').getSingleton('second');
Ti.API.info('second: ' + possiblyAnotherOtherThing.name);
```

The Output is:

```
[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/sim/MyApp.app/app.js, resource: app_js
[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/sim/MyApp.app/Singleton.js, resource: Singleton_js
[INFO] first: first
[INFO] second: first
```

Why is it then that circular references like the following don't work? (I might have already ansered this myself, comment/answer on it if you like).

**app.js**

```
require('Banana');
```

**Pinapple.js**

```
require('Banana');
```

**Banana.js**

```
require('Pineapple');
```

Because the output is this:

```
[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/simulator/MyApp.app/app.js, resource: app_js
[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/simulator/MyApp.app/Banana.js, resource: Banana_js
[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/simulator/MyApp.app/Pineapple.js, resource: Pineapple_js
[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/simulator/MyApp.app/Banana.js, resource: Banana_js
[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/simulator/MyApp.app/Pineapple.js, resource: Pineapple_js
[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/simulator/MyApp.app/Banana.js, resource: Banana_js
[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/simulator/MyApp.app/Pineapple.js, resource: Pineapple_js
[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/simulator/MyApp.app/Banana.js, resource: Banana_js

/* etcetera (total of 15 times back and forth) */

[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/simulator/MyApp.app/Pineapple.js, resource: Pineapple_js
[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/simulator/MyApp.app/Banana.js, resource: Banana_js
[DEBUG] loading: /path/to/simulator/MyApp.app/Pineapple.js, resource: Pineapple_js
[ERROR] Script Error = Maximum call stack size exceeded. (unknown file)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I too am using CommonJS modules in Appcelerator Titanium to build a mobile app. What I did to resolve the circular dependency problem was this: if A and B are the 2 circularly-dependent modules, require(A) in B, and vice-versa *just before you actually need to use it*. In my case, I needed A inside B only when a certain button got clicked, so I put a require(A) in B inside the button's click event listener. Hope that helps.