# Objects within Exports Object

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js, module

So I've been looking at this post: [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-nodejs-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it) and have been trying to make sense of it within the scope of JavaScript objects.

So if I have this in `game.js`:

```
var myObj = function() { 

    this.function1 = function(){
        ...
    };
};

exports.myObj = myObj;
```

In the other file I'm assuming that I would do something like this:

```
var RequiredObj = require('game.js');
```

or

```
var RequiredObj = require('game.js').myObj;
```

Where I get lost is how to then use this object and its function, also how to create a new instance of this object.

Would it be something like this?

```
RequiredObj.myObj.function1();
```

and

```
RequiredObj.myObj = new RequiredObj.myObj();
```

Also is there any limit to how big the object I'm passing is? Because in my actual script my game object is huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the "*other file*" is in the same directory as `game.js`, something like this should work:

```
var game = require('./game.js');

var mo = new game.myObj();

mo.function1();
```

A few things to note:

- Modules within your project should be specified [with a path](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) -- leading with `./`, `../`, or `/`. Otherwise, `require` will only search for the module as a [core module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules) or in [`node_modules` folders](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) (e.g., via [npm install](https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html)).
- `myObj` appears to be a constructor and `function1` would be an instance method. So, `RequiredObj.myObj.function1()` will error as no instance is created.
- On the other hand, `RequiredObj.myObj = new RequiredObj.myObj()` should work... *once*. This line sets over the reference to the constructor with a reference to an instance, rendering the constructor (mostly) inaccessible. ("*Mostly*" because it can still be available as `RequiredObj.myObj.constructor`, but declaring a new variable for the instance is generally simpler.)

> Also is there any limit to how big the object I'm passing is?

ECMAScript doesn't define any explicit limits on the size of an `Object`. Though, you'll of course be limited by the hardware used to execute the application.

Comment: Thanks. This was very thorough.