# same var name as function name in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a bit confused with the code below, can we create class in js this way?

```
module.exports = function testname(paramas){
  testname.test = function(req, res){
  //some code here
  }
  return testname;
}
```

should not we use this.test instead of function name.test?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-nodejs-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it Read this answer for more info about module.exports

Comment: If you want to know a bit more about OOP in JS: http://howtonode.org/prototypical-inheritance

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Your current code is a function that returns itself and creates a property on itself for each call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ClassName.methodname` creates static members, while `this.methodname` creates instance members

```
function MyClass () {
  this.fn = function () {
    // instance member function
  }
}

MyClass.anotherFn = function () {
  // Static member function
}
```

If you want to create some variables which should be encapsulated within the class objects when you create them, use `this.var`.

However, if you want a data member to be shared among all the instances of the same class then use `ClassName.var`