# What does exports mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Hi I was just looking at some sample code for some class and I was wondering why are the functions in routes/index.js assigned to be properties of the exports object? for example this function:

```
    exports.index = function(req, res){
      console.log("yes")
    };
```

What does exports do here and why is it used?

Comment: Is `exports` an object defined elsewhere in the code?

Comment: This question may provide some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-nodejs-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it

Comment: With no other information, `exports` is just a variable. You're then setting `exports.index` to a function.

Comment: nope this is the first time you see exports in the code

Comment: Must be `node.js` then.