# Include an array from another file (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, include

I have a file which contains code to iterate over a very large array. I'd rather not have the array in the same file as the code to keep things clean. However, I'm not sure how to include the file which contains my array and properly access the individual elements for my iteration. I'd rather not use a JSON object because I don't need `key -> value`.

Comment: Use `require` and just return the array from the file

Comment: indeed `export`  your large array, and `require` it where you need it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it. And the offical docs: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like everyone else is saying, you can use `require` and put the function into the `exports`:

myOtherFile.js

```
exports.largeArrayFunction = function() {
     //do stuff
     return stuff;
}
```

myMainNodeFile.js

```
var otherFile = require("myOtherFile.js");
var myArray = otherFile.largeArrayFunction();
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked. Brought a new issue with the `http` module, but at least I'm going forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Either use a regular JavaScript file:

```
module.exports = [1, 2, 3]
```

Or a JSON file, which can also be a simple Array:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Then include it using require:

```
var arr = require('./array.js'); // Or './array.json'

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // arr[i] ...
}
```

Comment: .js and .json files are handled differently by node require(). Hence the above answer.