# How to access output from Node.js' request module

Tags: node.js, request, web-scraping, cheerio

There are several tutorials that describe how to scrape websites with `request` and `cheerio`. In these tutorials they send the output to the console or stream the DOM with `fs` into a file as seen in the example below.

```
request(link, function (err, resp, html) {
  if (err) return console.error(err)
  var $ = cheerio.load(html),
      img = $('#img_wrapper').data('src');
  console.log(img);
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('img_link.txt'));
```

But what if I would like to process the output during script execution? How can I access the output or send it back to the calling function? I, of course, could load `img_link.txt` and get the information from there, but this would be to costly and doesn't make sense.

Comment: The output is `html` you have in request callback. You do not need to 'send it back', instead process it **inside** the callback.

Comment: I tried this solution already, but for processing I need variables from outside that are not accessible during execution time.

Comment: Yep, it seems i got the idea. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the pipe all together.

```
request(link, function (err, resp, html) {
  if (err) return console.error(err)

  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  var img = $('#img_wrapper').data('src'); // the var img now has the src attr of some image

  return img; // Will return the src attr
});
```

---

**Update**

By your comments, it seems like your request function is working as expected, but the problem is rather accessing the data from another module.

I suggest you read this [*Purpose of Node.js module.exports and how you use it*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it).

This is also a [good resource article](http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/) describing how *require* and *exports* are working.

- Put the code above in a module
- Use the `module.exports`
- Require the module in another file

Comment: If I do this, I get an `undefined`.

Comment: If you `console.log(img)`, do you get the src attr?

Comment: Yes, I do. But as I am fairly new to node.js I start to understand what my real problem is: When I build a module with a callback, require it in another module and use it, how would I access the data from the calling module? If I just return the data as in your example I always get an `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, it looks like your problem is the way `module.exports` works in node.js. I updated my answer with a few resources.

Comment: Thanks for the information and your patience with a node.js noob! I will check it out. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap request in a function that will callback with `html`

```
function(link, callback){
  request(link, function(err, im, body){
    callback(err, body);
  });
});
```

Then assign it to `exports` and use in any other module.

Comment: I created the module and required it in the calling module and logged the output to the console. But now I have the same problem. I start to understand, that I have a general lack of understanding how to access the data within a module call. Returning the data or assign it to a global variable didn't do the trick! So what is the best way to get the information back into the global scope?

Comment: In general, you should wait for all async tasks to end, e.g. with request it should first do a round-trip to the url you are requesting and only after that trip you will have `body`. If you try to `console.log(body)` before (read this as 'outside of request callback function') the request finished you get `undefined`. Read some tutorial on async programming in Node. It's the very basic concept that is hard to get for the first time but very simple once you understand it.