# When creating a definition file in Typescript, how can I add an API key

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript, and would like to create a d.ts definition file for a JavaScript library, [moviedb-js](https://github.com/danzajdband/moviedb), which can retreive movie information from [TheMovieDb](http://www.themoviedb.org/). I've looked for an existing definition at the [Definitely Typed repository](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped), and read [Fenton's guide](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Complex-TypeScript-Definitions-Made-Easy/) on creating a definition file, among others, however, I'm stuck with translating the following JavaScript bit:

```
var MovieDB = require('moviedb')('your api key');
```

When creating a module, I have something along the lines of

```
declare module 'moviedb' { ... }
```

And in my TypeScript code, I import it with:

```
import moviedb = require('moviedb')
```

Clearly, without an API key, this doesn't work, and adding the key as in the JavaScript example didn't work either. So how can I rewrite the module definition in such a way that I can define the API key that is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the concept `moviedb.d.ts`

```
declare module MovieDB{
     export interface IMovieDB{
         searchMovie(params:any,callback:Function):IMovieDB;
         // Add other methods here
     }
}
declare module 'moviedb' { 
    function apiKetAcceptor(key:string):MovieDB.IMovieDB;
    export = apiKeyAcceptor;
}
```

To use it you reference + import:

```
/// <reference path='../path/to/moviedb.d.ts'/>
import moviedb = require('moviedb');
var MovieDB = moviedb('your api key');
MovieDB.searchMovie({query: 'Alien' }, function(err, res){
  console.log(res);
});
```

For a detailed example look at Node.js definitions https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I'm not sure I completely get it (and I don't have my code with me now to test it). Basically, I would need to replace apiKeyAcceptor with the appropriate function in moviedb.js (https://github.com/danzajdband/moviedb/blob/master/lib/moviedb.js). Is that so? Or maybe you would be so kind, and have a look at this link, and complete the example, i.e. which function do I need to add, and how would I call it?

Comment: @ErikVullings alright, I've updated the answer with *untested* code. Let me know if something is *off*

Comment: Thanks for your update! I'll test it later, but it is looking good, so I've already accepted the answer. If something is wrong, I will tell you, of course.

Answer (score 1):

@basarat: I've checked your response, and it was working well. Thanks again!

As a side note, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it) also really helpful in understanding the construction that was used to add the API key.

So what do I have:

MovieScanner.ts

```
export class TmbdMovieScanner {
    movieDb: MovieDB.IMovieDB;

    constructor() {
        this.movieDb = moviedb('YOUR API KEY');

        // For testing purposes
        this.movieDb.searchMovie({ query: "Aliens" }, (err, movies) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error: ' + err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(movies);            
        });
        this.movieDb.movieInfo({ id: 666 }, (err, curMovie) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error: ' + err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(curMovie.overview);
        });
    }
}
```

moviedb.d.ts (still incomplete):

```
declare module 'moviedb' {
    function apiKeyAcceptor(key: string): MovieDB.IMovieDB;
    export = apiKeyAcceptor;
}

declare module MovieDB {
    export interface IMovieDB {
        searchMovie(params: SearchOptions, callback: (err: any, movies: SearchResults) => void): void;
        movieInfo(options: InfoOptions, callback: (err: any, curMovie: Movie) => void): void;
    }

    export interface SearchOptions {
        query: string;
    }

    export interface InfoOptions {
        id: number;
    }

    export interface SearchResults {
        page         : number;
        results      : SearchResult[];
        total_Pages  : number;
        total_results: number;
    }

    export interface SearchResult {
        adult         : boolean;
        backdrop_path : string;
        id            : number;
        original_title: string;
        release_date  : Date;
        poster_path   : string;
        popularity    : number;
        title         : string;
        vote_average  : number;
        vote_count    : number;
    }

    export interface Movie {
        adult                : boolean;
        backdrop_path        : string;
        belongs_to_collection: any;
        budget               : number;
        genres               : Genre[];
        homepage             : string;
        id                   : number;
        imdb_id              : number;
        original_title       : string;
        overview             : string;
        popularity           : number;
        poster_path          : string;
        production_companies : ProductionCompany[];
        production_countries : ProductionCountry[];
        release_date         : Date;
        revenue              : number;
        runtime              : number;
        spoken_languages     : SpokenLanguage[];
        status               : string;
        tagline              : string;
        title                : string;
        vote_average         : number;
        vote_count           : number;
    }

    export interface Genre {
        id  : number;
        name: string;
    }

    export interface ProductionCompany {
        id  : number;
        name: string;
    }

    export interface ProductionCountry {
        iso_3166_1: number;
        name      : string;
    }

    export interface SpokenLanguage {
        iso_639_1: number;
        name     : string;
    }
}
```