# Testing Emberjs app using QUnit and Karma fails due to `ReferenceError: Faye is not defined`

Tags: ember.js, scope, qunit, faye, karma-qunit

I Was testing EmberJs application with Qunit and karma runner and it was working all good.
Then I had to integrate faye into the application which went well but then on running my test suite, it shows following error and crashes:

> ReferenceError: Faye is not defined

The error is thrown where, I am defining the client in emberjs

```
client = new Faye.Client(uri);
```

Though this works in development, staging but not in testing.
Overhere, `uri = "http://localhost:9292/faye"`

faye.js is included in vendor.js(single js file which have all the js plugins including ember.js and ember-data.js itself) which is loaded before app.js(file where above line exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of that weird behavior is related to the following lines in Faye:

`if (typeof module !== 'undefined')
  module.exports = Faye;
else if (typeof window !== 'undefined')
  window.Faye = Faye;`

Source: https://github.com/faye/faye/blob/master/javascript/faye.js#L143
So if *module* is not undefined(meaning it is defined) then **module.exports** will be set object,  if not, **window.Faye** will be set.
If you use a debugger and set a breakpoint on that line you will that module is **actually defined**, why? it is a QUnit global helper method!
Why Faye does this? I guess because it can be run in a NodeJS environment (you can read more about module.exports [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5311377/261377)).
As I see it you have 2 possible solutions:

- Require Faye before QUnit.
- Patch Faye to ignore the existence of module in window.

I've encountered the same behavior while using [Teaspoon](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon) with QUnit.
Making Teaspoon require Faye before QUnit seems like a bad idea and will be probably in ugly hack.
I've ended up with patching Faye to make it skip the module check, not so beautiful either, but I believe this is reasonable.