# emberjs - don't include bower component in my distribution dir without giving any errors

Tags: ember.js, faye

I'm trying to use Faye in my ember project. 
I have this import line in my brocfile

```
app.import('bower_components/faye-browser/index.js');
```

And the corresponding bower.json entry looks like this:

```
"faye-browser": "http://af2447c3.fanoutcdn.com/bayeux/static/faye-browser.js",
```

Just to be sure I checked and indeed I have a file named "bower_components/faye-browser/index.js".

However, no matter what I do and how I build, the content of faye-browser/index.js simple does not exist anywhere in vendor.js, nor anywhere else in the output folder (/dist).

Ember don't give me any error or explanation as to why it ignores this file. It just ignores it, and "Faye" is undefined in my ember js.

I've seen this question already: [Testing Emberjs app using QUnit and Karma fails due to `ReferenceError: Faye is not defined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243632/testing-emberjs-app-using-qunit-and-karma-fails-due-to-referenceerror-faye-is/27830540#27830540)
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had similar experience. In my project I depend on jQuery UI and it is imported in similar manner. I upgraded from ember-cli 0.2.7 to 1.13.1 and all of a sudden jQuery UI is not present. I haven't pinpointed the exact root cause yet but it might be related to the new ember-cli version. Need to downgrade to ember-cli 0.2.7 to see if the problem will disappear. Haven't done it yet though.

In case you use ember-cli 1.13.x you could try with previous version and see if the issue will be gone.

UPDATE:
I think I found the problem. The new ember-cli version replaces Brocfile.js with ember-cli-build.js.
Right now I have both files in my root folder and my customizations are applied in Brocfile.js (because the old version used this file) however they need to be moved to ember-cli-build.js.
You might be in the same situation and this could be the reason why applying changes to Brocfile.js doesn't change the output vendor.js file.

Comment: yes you are right, the Brocfile seems to be replaced by ember-cli-build.js. and the fact that "ember install xyz" made changes to brocfile.js instead of ember-cli-builds.js really confused me..  thanks :)