# What is happening here in this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone tell me what is happening here?I only know that it is requiring some core modules.

```
var inherits = require('util').inherits;
var express = require('express')();
```

Comment: And it is doing just that. The second module is executed immediately, though.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `util` module has exported an object that contains (probably amongst others) a function under the key `inherits`:

```
exports = {
    inherits: function() ...
}
```

The `express` module on the other hand, has directly exported a whole function, and that function is immediately invoked and the result assigned to the variable `express`.

```
module.exports = exports = function() {
    return ...
}
```

It is *likely* that the function has also returned an object containing key/value pairs of functions, just like you'd get from a normal `exports` object.

See also [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334)