# Custom Error Class as a Node module to send custom error response

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, node-modules, custom-error-handling

Here I created Custom Error class in Node.js. I created this ErrorClass to send Custom error response of api call.

I want to catch this `CustomError` class in `Bluebird Catch promises`.

```
Object.defineProperty(Error.prototype, 'message', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true
});

Object.defineProperty(Error.prototype, 'stack', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true
});

Object.defineProperty(Error.prototype, 'toJSON', {
    value: function () {
        var alt = {};
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).forEach(function (key) {
            alt[key] = this[key];
        }, this);

        return alt;
    },
    configurable: true
});

Object.defineProperty(Error.prototype, 'errCode', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true
});

function CustomError(errcode, err, message) {
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    this.name = 'CustomError';
    this.message = message;
    this.errcode = errcode;
    this.err = err;
}

CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

I wanna convert this into **node-module** but I am not getting how to do that.

Comment: Why are you adding `message`, `stack` and `toJSON` to `Error.prototype`? Why not just set them in `CustomError`?

Comment: @thefourtheye why define `message`/`stack` at all, they are already being inherited from `Error.prototype`.

Comment: @James True. Why didn't I think of that? :D

Comment: @James Ah, I see why OP does that. He is making everything `enumerable`.

Comment: @thefourtheye ah, so they are. To be honest I only scanned the actual implementation as that wasn't really relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: @thefourtheye Yeah ,True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I want to catch this CustomError class in Bluebird Catch promises.**

Quoting [bluebird's documentation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#catchfunction-errorclassfunction-predicate-function-handler---promise),

> For a parameter to be considered a type of error that you want to filter, you need the constructor to have its `.prototype` property be `instanceof Error`.
>
> Such a constructor can be minimally created like so:
>
> ```
> function MyCustomError() {}
> MyCustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
> ```
>
> Using it:
>
> ```
> Promise.resolve().then(function() {
>     throw new MyCustomError();
> }).catch(MyCustomError, function(e) {
>     //will end up here now
> });
> ```

So, you can `catch` the custom error object, like this

```
Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    throw new CustomError();
}).catch(CustomError, function(e) {
    //will end up here now
});
```

> **I wanna convert this into node-module but I am not getting how to do that.**

You just have to assign whatever you want to export as part of the module, to `module.exports`. In this case, most likely, you might want to export the `CustomError` function and it can be done like this

```
module.exports = CustomError;
```

Read more about `module.exports` in this question, [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5311334/1903116)

Answer (score 1):

A node module is nothing more than an exported class. In your example, if you export your `CustomError` class i.e.

```
module.exports = CustomError;
```

Then you would be able to import the module from another class

```
var CustomError = require("./CustomError");
...
throw new CustomError();
```