# What is the Best practice of exports function in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning nodejs , I find two way to exports our function in Nodejs , but I can not find what is difference between in those 
The first is

```
module.exports.UserService = (function () {
return {
      getUser:getUser
}
})()
```

And another

```
var getUser=function(searchInfo,res){}
module.exports.getUser=getUser
```

Is there any disadvantage or advantage of using , or any other best practice for exports function

Comment: I think this post will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/5311377/2885628

Comment: I should've thought a little more before posting. +1!

Answer (score 0):

I always find it better to use the first notation (exporting the object  via its reference) because:

1. it allows you to build the object incrementally, and
2. allows you to reference the object within itself.

e.g.:

```
var Obj = {};
Obj.attrs = { "prop1": "val1", "prop2": "val2" };
addSomeProperties(Obj); /* possibly based on Obj.attrs */
module.exports = Obj;
```