# how would you wrap function constructor object method with prototype in a single module using exports or module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a "grid" module with this code, i've tried different way using exports or module.exports to use it in a other file but didn't work. I want to have a require('./grid.js') and use this objects, functions in an other file.

```js
function Vector(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
Vector.prototype.plus = function(other) {
  return new Vector(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
};

function Grid(width, height) {
  this.space = new Array(width * height);
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}
Grid.prototype.isInside = function(vector) {
  return vector.x >= 0 && vector.x < this.width &&
         vector.y >= 0 && vector.y < this.height;
};
Grid.prototype.get = function(vector) {
  return this.space[vector.x + this.width * vector.y];
};
Grid.prototype.set = function(vector, value) {
  this.space[vector.x + this.width * vector.y] = value;
};

var directions = {
  "n":  new Vector( 0, -1),
  "ne": new Vector( 1, -1),
  "e":  new Vector( 1,  0),
  "se": new Vector( 1,  1),
  "s":  new Vector( 0,  1),
  "sw": new Vector(-1,  1),
  "w":  new Vector(-1,  0),
  "nw": new Vector(-1, -1)
};

function randomElement(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

var directionNames = "n ne e se s sw w nw".split(" ");
```

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER:** I made an easier exemple based on Alexander M

```js
// ================== lib.js

function User(n, p) {
 this.n = n;
 this.p = p;
}

User.prototype.user = function() {
 console.log("user: " + this.n + ", pass: " + this.p);
};

function Client(n, p, m) {
 User.call(this, n, p);
 this.m = m;
}

Client.prototype = new User();

Client.prototype.full = function() {
 console.log(this.m);
};

module.exports = 
{
 User,
 Client
};
```

```js
// ============= FILE.JS

var mod = require('./lib.js');

var john = new mod.Client("john", "mskjqh", "john@gmail.com");

john.user();
john.full();
console.log(john);

// input
// user: john, pass: mskjqh
// john@gmail.com
// User { n: 'john', p: 'mskjqh', m: 'john@gmail.com' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to export everything, right?

```
function Vector(x, y) {
  ...
}

function Grid(width, height){
  ...
}

module.exports = {
  Vector: Vector,
  Grid : Grid,
  directionNames : directionNames,
  ...
};
```

If you're using node.js 4+, you can use short ES6 syntax:

```
module.exports = {
  Vector,
  Grid,
  directionNames,
  ...
};
```

Then, in another file, you'd have

```
var Vector = require('./path/to/grid.js').Vector;
```

Or

```
var grid = require('./path/to/grid.js');
var Vector = grid.Vector;
```

You might also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it) useful.