# Testing Error on node.js function with Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, tdd, mocha.js

With Node.js installed and testing with mocha,

I have two files, numbers.js and test.js in the same directory

Following the top answer: [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

**numbers.js**

```
var myFunc = function myFunc() {
      return 10;
};

exports.myFunc = myFunc;
```

**test.js**

```
var assert = require('assert');
var numbers = require('./numbers');

describe('numbers', function() {
    it('first function returns 10', function() {
            var result = numbers.myFunc;
            assert.equal(result, 10);
     });
});
```

But when running `$ mocha` it returns the error:

```
AssertionError: [Function: myFunc] == 10
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your `myFunc` function.  Add the parens

```
describe('numbers', function() {
    it('first function returns 10', function() {
                  var result = numbers.myFunc(); <<<<<<

                      assert.equal(result, 10);
                        });
});
```

Comment: I didn't try that, but it did get me further! However I get a new assertion error
It says `AssertionError: undefined == 1`

Comment: I see, I had removed the () after changing myfunc to myFunc and that caused another problem.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Inspect your **numbers** module is properly required or not.

```
var numbers = require('../numbers'); // Check path of file numbers.js
```

If yes, write :

```
var result = numbers.myFunc(); // your module exports 'myFunc' property not 'myfunc'
assert.equal(result, 10); // your function return '10' instead of '1'
```

Comment: I updated the code, now I put numbers.js and test.js in the same place so I think its properly required, I also fixed numbers.myFunc. That helped and I got further, but a new problem. Mocha gives the error `AssertionError: [Function: myFunc] == 10`

Comment: Yes , It was my mistake, I forgot to add '()' after myFunc.Basically its a function so you need to call it.