# Nodejs module exports confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have a confusion with module.exports. As far as I understood `module.exports` is an object that is exposed to other modules,

```
exports=module.exports={}
```

But in the index.js of morgan package in node.js I found this.

```
module.exports = morgan
module.exports.compile = compile
module.exports.format = format
module.exports.token = token
```

`morgan`, `compile`, `format` and `token` are all functions.

Can you explain whats happening here? How is a function(morgan) assigned to module.exports ? After the first line is executed, is module.exports a function instead of an JSON object?

Comment: i read that "Nodejs module exports confusion". (woulda been +1 for that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Node module basically works like this:

```
var module = {
    exports: {}
};
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {

    // your module code here

})(module.exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname);

var exported = module.exports;
```

By default, `exports`, and `module.exports` both point to the same object. You can add properties to the object as normal. However, what if you want to return a function or some other object instead of just the default standard object?

In that case, you can set `module.exports` to something else, and that will be the new exported object.

```
module.exports = function() {};
```

And of course, that function can have properties too, so your code is kind-of like this:

```
module.exports = function(){};
module.exports.compile = function() {};
module.exports.format = function() {};
module.exports.token = function() {};
```

Which would be equivalent to:

```
var morgan = function() {};
var compile = function() {};
var format = function() {};
var token = function() {};

morgan.compile = compile;
morgan.format = format;
morgan.token = token;
module.exports = morgan;
```

> How is a function(morgan) assigned to module.exports ?  After the first line is executed, is module.exports a function instead of an JSON object?

Yes, `module.exports` will be a function, in place of the default object (however there is no JSON here, JSON is not a JavaScript object, but an encoding format).

Comment: After those 4 lines are executed can you tell me how would the module.exports look like?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi It would be a function object, with 3 function object properties.

Comment: so format, compile and token will become function variables of module.exports which is a function?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi Yes, they will be available as properties when you require them.

Comment: this is what it looks like { [Function: morgan]
  compile: [Function: compile],
  format: [Function: format],
  token: [Function: token] }

Comment: Since I code in python and new to js I did not get [Function: morgan] part. Can you please explain?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi I'm not sure what you mean, but `[Function: morgan]` is just how the console represents the named function object. You would get the same with `console.log(morgan);`

Comment: Why isn't there a  comma after after it?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi Because the commas delimit the properties, and that function itself is not a property, but the variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this answer for a more in-depth explanation:

[What is the purpose of node js module exports and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it?rq=1)

Morgan is simply adding parameters to the module being exported (in this case `compile`, `format`, and `token`. When you require the module in your application using something like `morgan = require('morgan')`, you can then call `morgan.format` to return the format that was appended to the object.

Hope that clears things up a bit!

Comment: After those 4 lines are executed can you tell me how would the module.exports look like?

Answer (score 0):

module.exports is an object that is exposed to other modules and files. This allows a convenient way to export variables, functions and more javascript features.

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) , when you initialize any variable to {} you are initializing an object.

An object can contain variables and functions, this is one of the things that makes Javascript really cool. You can easily pass complex objects with functions as parameters and do real nice clean code.

So, short story, think about module.exports as an object that is exposed to other modules and files with variables and functions. Just like passing an Object Oriented object as a parameter in Java or Ruby.

Here is easily explained: [Read More](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)

Answer (score 0):

> Can you explain whats happening here?

An assignment statement is happening.

```
// path-to-my-module.js
module.exports = morgan
module.exports.compile = compile
module.exports.format = format
module.exports.token = token
```

For each of these 4 statements, there is an assignment statement. Looking at the first line, `module.exports = morgan`, that would mean the `module.exports` *object* is going to have a property called `morgan` with its value being the value of the identifier `morgan`

So when you use it like this:

```
var m = require('./path-to-my-module.js');
console.log(m.morgan);
console.log(m);
```