# require and export confusion in express.js (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to make my socket.io connection modular, to make it run once even if I need it anytime and everywhere. How to I export it?

```
var server = require("http").Server(express);  
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
server.listen(5000);
io.on('connection', function(client) {
  client.on('order_'+userId, function(data) {
      io.emit('order_'+userId,data); // emit to cilent of dashboard
  });
});
```

How does required work? I'm seeing different pattern like

```
var moment = require('moment');
```

or sometime

```
var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
```

In my case I need not to assign it to any variable, and want it to execute on the fly. Possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of Node.js module.exports and how do you use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

`require()` returns what the module exports. It can be either an `Object`, a `function`, or even a `String` or a `Number`. It's usually either `Object` or `function` though. For example, `var server = require('http')` returns an `Object`, which has a `Server()` method (which you call in the first line of your code sample). It's up to the author of the package, really.

Your code seems OK to me. `socket.io` is assigned to a variable because that's how you reference it later. `io.on('connection', ...)` is effectively only called once. This will wait for a connection, and every time a connection event happens, `function(client) {...}` will be called. There is no major performance problem with this implementation.