# Not able to use custom functions in webpack with require

Tags: reactjs, webpack, require

I am creating a progressive web app using react and webpack.
I have successfully configured everything and able to start the development.
Now, i have many helper functions like :

```
function getCookie(name) {
      var start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=");
      var len = start + name.length + 1;
      if ((!start) && (name != document.cookie.substring(0, name.length))) {
        return null;
      }
      if (start == -1) return null;
      var end = document.cookie.indexOf(';', len);
      if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(len, end));
}
```

So, for this i have created another js file : helper.jsx.
Now my helper.js contains the above function as it is. Now i want to use the above function in another react component.

I am doing a require in my component :

```
var helper = require("helper");
```

and trying to call the function using :

```
helper.getCookie('user');
```

Which is giving me helper.getCookie is not a defined.
Please tell me how can i create a helper js and use the functions of helper js in my react components.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to export the function using module.exports:

```
function getCookie(name) {
      var start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=");
      var len = start + name.length + 1;
      if ((!start) && (name != document.cookie.substring(0, name.length))) {
        return null;
      }
      if (start == -1) return null;
      var end = document.cookie.indexOf(';', len);
      if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(len, end));
}

module.exports = {
    getCookie: getCookie
};
```

Comment: Thanx Ori, Just another question with a different context. I making some ajax calls in my project to a php file which is in my project's libraries folder. So how can i have my php files execute in webpack server?

Comment: is there any way i can execute the php files in webpack server? Or should i include the whole project in a different server which would be running in a different port?

Comment: As far as I know you can't execute php files in the webpack dev server, but I haven't touched PHP in eons. The 2nd solution should work, but you'll have to enable CORS on you PHP server, and I don't really know how to do that.