# Showing 'db.get is not a function' NodeJs, MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Making a voting app that consists of following 2 models users and polls and database consisting of two collections users and polls.

User.js

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = new Schema({
    github: {
        id: String,
        displayName: String,
        username: String,
        publicRepos: Number
    },
    nbrClicks: {
        clicks: Number
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Poll.js

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Poll = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    creator: String,
    choices: [String],
    votes: [Number]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Poll', Poll);
```

and this is the route part

```
'use strict';
require('dotenv').load();
var path = process.cwd();
var ClickHandler = require(path + '/app/controllers/clickHandler.server.js');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGO_URI);

module.exports = function (app, passport) {
    function isLoggedIn (req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        } else {
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    }

    var clickHandler = new ClickHandler();
    app.route('/').get(isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        //console.log(display-name.profile-value);
        res.render(path + '/public/index.jade');
    });
    app.route('/polls').get(function(req, res) { 
        var polls = db.get('polls');
        console.log(polls);
        res.render(path + '/public/polls.jade');
    })
```

This is the error being thrown

```
TypeError: db.get is not a function
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/routes/index.js:39:22
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:325:9)
at SessionStrategy.authenticate (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:71:10)
at attempt (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:348:16)
at authenticate (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:349:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at initialize (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/initialize.js:53:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
```

Comment: I'm gonna guess the problem is that `db.get` isn't a function.  You're going to want to do something with `Poll.find` [the mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to import Poll into your route file.

```
var Poll = require('./PATH_TO_POLL/Poll');
```

Then as @numbers1311407 has described, if you want to return all the saved Poll documents try:

```
Poll.find(function (err, polls) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(polls);
})
```

**edit:**

More information on module.exports can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311334/what-is-the-purpose-of-node-js-module-exports-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Comment: but, actually I have exported the Poll model using module.exports, so cant it be called simply without using require method elsewhere in the directory..?

Comment: Your welcome, happy to help. You have to require `'Poll'`, what you call it here `module.exports = mongoose.model('Poll', Poll);` indicates by convention you should call it with the same name, but you could call it anything. Stick to the naming convention though, it makes your code easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

this error is comes when using mongodb **community server**. so you need to use mongoose or another one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).